# Retrieve a single file from a repository

Tags: git, git-checkout, sparse-checkout, git-sparse-checkout

What is the most efficient mechanism (in respect to data transferred and disk space used) to get the contents of a single file from a remote git repository?

So far I've managed to come up with:

```
git clone --no-checkout --depth 1 git@github.com:foo/bar.git && cd bar && git show HEAD:path/to/file.txt
```

This still seems overkill.

What about getting multiple files from the repo?

Comment: Aaw. I would love it if there was a built in way to do the equivalent of "cat-remote" and "tag-remote".

Comment: I have this same problem I want to have the same license file in 2 repos; edit the file in 1 repo then have it auto update the copy in the other repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to checkout only one file from git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository)

Answer (score 181):

In git version 1.7.9.5 this seems to work to export a single file from a remote

```
git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md | tar xO
```

This will cat the contents of the file `README.md`.

Comment: ... Except it doesn't work on GitHub. Dang. :( https://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/322818593748303873

Comment: This doesn't seem to yield the raw file but rather a tar file with just a single file.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe just add ` | tar -x` to the command.

`git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md | tar -x`
`cat README.md`

Comment: You can use `tar -xO` to output to STDOUT for piping, e.g. `FILE=README.md && git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD "$FILE" | tar -xO "$FILE"`

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, but I get "fatal: Operation not supported by protocol." in response from Git. Argh.

Comment: This apparently works but I've an issue with it: the md5sum of what I get back after untaring does not match with what I have on the git repo
this is what I get back:
  md5sum README.md
  f8359c59f8ebc61adfcef6c19aea0a97  README.md
this is what's on the git repo:
  md5sum README.md 
  2ff7094d2cb8d574b4ca04a95ceff534  README.md

Comment: Will export a header and a trailer with lots of nulls

Comment: This answer is a good start but the problem it doesn't make clear is that the concatenated contents of `README.md` will include a bunch of header junk, since its actually a tar file, not just the plain text. In the end I had to use `git archive --remote ${remoteGitRepo} HEAD ${sourceFilePath} | tar --extract --directory ${tempDir}` and then read the file at `${tempDir}/${sourceFilePath}` in order to get a clean version of the source file text, which is pretty much what the OP's original solution was doing.

Comment: I get the error: __fatal: Operation not supported by protocol.__ when I attempt to use it on a repo hosted on GitHub. If this method doesn't work on the protocol used by GitHub, then it can be safely regarded as "unreliable".

Comment: is it possible to specify a branch?

Comment: @RobHoward For GitHub, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609835/git-export-from-github-remote-repository

Comment: @arod Yes, just specify the branch name in place of `HEAD`.

Comment: This does not work for a sha commit hash. From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-archive): "neither a relative commit like master nor a literal sha1 like abcd1234 is allowed"

Comment: If you're on Windows and don't have `tar`, you can use `powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Force`

Comment: Just for the distracted people, that's the letter O and not the number zero: `-xO`. It makes the output be stdout instead of saving the file in the current directory.

Comment: Doing a quick test, it looks like this doesn't work on GitHub, GitLab, or Forgejo.

Comment: Also doesn't work on BitBucket

Answer (score 86):

Following on from [Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-nar%c4%99bski)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126333/2378780).  `git archive` produces a tar or zip archive, so you need to pipe the output through tar to get the file content:

```
git archive --remote=git://git.foo.com/project.git HEAD:path/to/directory filename | tar -x
```

Will save a copy of 'filename' from the HEAD of the remote repository in the current directory.

The `:path/to/directory` part is optional.  If excluded, the fetched file will be saved to `<current working dir>/path/to/directory/filename`

In addition, if you want to enable use of `git archive --remote` on Git repositories hosted by git-daemon, you need to enable the daemon.uploadarch config option. See https://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html

Comment: If it is a text file and we want to save it to another part it is gut to use: 
| tar -xO > ~/destfile.ext

Comment: does it work with specific commit? (i.e. one specifies both specific file and commit)

Comment: Yes. Replace `HEAD` with the commit ID that you want to use. `HEAD` is an alias that refers to either the currently checked out commit (if applicable) or the tip of the default branch.

I wrote the above answer years ago and learned this morning that GitHub doesn't support `git archive`, so that makes it a lot less useful.

Comment: Looks like the best answer to me. Add a `v` as another option to `tar -x` doesn't hut.
Also it may be good to note that it works **also for a specific folder**, not only a single file :
`git archive --remote=git://git.foo.com/project.git HEAD path/to/folder/ | tar -xv`

Comment: **fatal: operation not supported by protocol**

Answer (score 47):

If there is **web interface** deployed (like gitweb, cgit, Gitorious, ginatra), you can use it to download single file ('raw' or 'plain' view).

If other side *enabled it*, you can use **[git archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html)**'s '`--remote=<URL>`' option (and possibly limit it to a directory given file resides in), for example:

```
$ git archive --remote=git@github.com:foo/bar.git --prefix=path/to/ HEAD:path/to/ |  tar xvf -
```

Comment: Note: the example was not tested!

Comment: For your own repositories you need to specifically enable upload-archive if using git-daemon (git:// style urls) with `git config daemon.uploadarch true` on the remote repository. By default git daemon disables remote archive with "fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: ..."

Comment: +1 The `git archive` approach was my first try - but then I noticed that requiring `tar` on the client machine wasn't exactly convenient for Windows users. We ended up fetching from our local `cgit` server. It works, but it's not as fast as I'd like it to be (and it still requires running `unix2dos` or similiar on Windows machines since we store files with Unix line endings in the Git repository).

Comment: Is there a GUI that can browse the remote git and where you can set off this `git archive...` command automatically in the background to see single files directly inside the gui?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Use -o fetched.zip. Also see --format=<fmt> option.

Comment: For what it's worth, it doesn't look like this works on GitHub hosted repositories. See https://help.github.com/articles/can-i-archive-a-repository and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/github/z8vLHcX0HxY

Comment: Append `|tar -xO` to write the file to stdout.

Answer (score 45):

**Not in general but if you are using Github:**

For me `wget` to the raw url turned out to be the best and easiest way to download one particular file.

Open the file in the browser and click on "Raw" button. Now refresh your browser, copy the url and do a `wget` or `curl` on it.

wget example:

```sh
wget 'https://github.abc.abc.com/raw/abc/folder1/master/folder2/myfile.py?token=DDDDnkl92Kw8829jhXXoxBaVJIYW-h7zks5Vy9I-wA%3D%3D' -O myfile.py
```

Curl example:

```sh
curl 'https://example.com/raw.txt' > savedFile.txt
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, and works for any raw txt one could find.

`curl https://example.com/raw.txt > savedFile.txt`

Comment: wget example doesn't work, curl example does though.

Comment: Works just fine for me. Did you put your url in quotes on the commandline ?

Comment: this does not preserve git history

Comment: The solution is asked for Git, the answer endorses Github is git and is nowheere related to git. It's based on additional APIs offered by a prominent git solution provider!

Comment: If u need a raw file content from github, just run curl with this url e.g.:
`curl 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SoliDry/api-generator/master/tests/functional/oas/openapi.yaml' > openapi_test.yaml`
It is easily accessible from UI btn `raw` btw.

Answer (score 18):

To export a single file from a remote:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md | tar -x
```

This will download the file `README.md` to your current directory.

If you want the contents of the file exported to STDOUT:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md | tar -xO
```

You can provide multiple paths at the end of the command.

Answer (score 11):

If no other answer worked (i.e. restrictive GitLab access), you can do a "selective-checkout" by:

1. `git clone --no-checkout --depth=1 --no-tags URL`
2. `git restore --staged DIR-OR-FILE`
3. `git checkout DIR-OR-FILE`

Although this solution is 100% git compliant and you can checkout a directory, it's not disk nor network optimal as doing a wget/curl on a file.

Comment: Doing a quick test, it looks like this is the correct answer for GitHub, GitLab, and Forgejo.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a solution to me: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/27/get-a-file-from-a-specific-revision.html

```
git show HEAD~4:index.html > local_file
```

where `4` means four revision from now and `~` is a tilde as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Make sure to notice that is it NOT the 'minus sign' '-' between 'HEAD' and '4', but the 'tilde' '~'. Apparently I haven't read the git docs well enough, or my glasses need updating ;-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to get the file from a remote repository though, like the OP needs.

Comment: Or: ```git show HEAD:./my_other_file > local_file``` if the file isn't in your root dir:)

Comment: Or: ```git show refs/remotes/my_remote/master:./my_file``` where refs path is your proper remote path retrieved by: ```git show-ref```

Comment: Kind request for all downvoters - please explain and clarify what's not OK - we are here to learn and share :)

Comment: @MichalStefanow: Mike Weller has it; specifically, this doesn't work on a remote repository. You need a local clone at the very least, even if you then have remotes set up on it.

Answer (score 8):

I solved in this way:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://git@gitlab.com/user/mi-repo.git BranchName /path-to-file/file_name | tar -xO /path-to-file/file_name > /path-to-save-the-file/file_name
```

If you want, you could replace "BranchName" for "HEAD"

Answer (score 7):

A nuanced variant of some of the answers here that answers the OP's question:

```
git archive --remote=git@archive-accepting-git-server.com:foo/bar.git \
  HEAD path/to/file.txt | tar -xO path/to/file.txt > file.txt
```

Comment: This does not work, github does not support git archive.

Comment: Err.. git is used for more than just GitHub

Comment: You explicitly set --remote to a github URL in your answer though ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Have amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

I use this

```bsh
$ cat ~/.wgetrc
check_certificate = off

$ wget https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery/master/grunt.js
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11339 (11K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `grunt.js'
```

Comment: Works for me even without wgetrc tweaks: `wget https://raw.github.com/bk322/bk_automates/master/bkubuntu/bkubuntu.bash`

Comment: My message is more helpful: `ERROR: Certificate verification error for raw.github.com: unable to get local issuer certificate.` **`To connect to raw.github.com insecurely, use '--no-check-certificate'.`**

Comment: This works for public repositories only. For private repositories you need authentication.

Comment: Mac didn't have wget, so I used curl but I had to use `curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/org/repo/master/file > outfile` otherwise it does not download if the file has already been downloaded

Answer (score 6):

This is specific for git repos hosted on **GitHub**

Try the *'api'* command of Github's command line app, `gh`, to make an authenticated call to  Github's *'get repository contents'* endpoint.

The basic command is:

```
$gh api /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/<path_to_the_file>
```

As an added bonus, when you do this from inside a directory that contains a clone of the repo you're trying to get the file from, the {owner} and {repo} part will be automatically filled in.

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content

The response will be a JSON object. If the <path_to_the_file> indeed points to a file, the JSON will include a 'size', 'name', several url fields to access the file, as well as a 'content' field, which is a base64 encoded version of the file contents.

To get the file contents, you can curl the value of the "download_url", or just decode the 'content' field. You can do that by piping the base64 command, like this:

```
$gh api /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/<path-to-the-file> --jq '.content' | base64 -d
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me the easiest way to use the following:

```
wget https://github.com/name/folder/file.zip?raw=true
```

Comment: Thank you, simple indeed. To get rid of '?raw=true' at the end of saved file one can use: ```-O your-file-name``` at the end of the command above.

Answer (score 4):

If you repository supports tokens (for example GitLab) then generate a token for your user then navigate to the file you will download and click on RAW output to get the URL. To download the file use:

```
curl --silent --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: replace_with_your_token' \
'http://git.example.com/foo/bar.sql' --output /tmp/bar.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

For single file, just use wget command.

First, follow the pic below to click "raw" to get the url, otherwise you will download code embedded in html. 
[image]

Then, the browser will open a new page with url start with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...

just enter the command in the terminal:

```
#wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...
```

A while the file will put in your folder.

Comment: Yep, this also works nice within Python, or other programming languages, with a REST-funcionality. For example for downloading modules from different repositories..

Answer (score 3):

If your Git repository hosted on Azure-DevOps (VSTS) you can retrieve a single file with [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/items/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

The format of this API looks like this:

```
 https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={pathToFile}&api-version=4.1?download=true
```

For example:

```
 https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items?scopePath=/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml&download=true&api-version=4.1
```

Comment: It requires api token, doesn't it?

Comment: Depends how you run the api

Answer (score 3):

The following 2 commands worked for me:

`git archive --remote={remote_repo_git_url} {branch} {file_to_download} -o {tar_out_file}`

Downloads `file_to_download` as `tar` archive from `branch` of remote repository whose url is `remote_repo_git_url` and stores it in `tar_out_file`

`tar -x -f {tar_out_file}.tar` extracts the `file_to_download` from `tar_out_file`

Answer (score 1):

I use curl, it works with public repos or those using https basic authentication via a web interface.

`curl -L --retry 20 --retry-delay 2 -O https://github.com/ACCOUNT/REPO/raw/master/PATH/TO/FILE/FILE.TXT -u USER:PASSWORD`

I've tested it on github and bitbucket, works on both.

Comment: work also on gitlab and gitea !

Answer (score 1):

[Yisrael Dov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18331440/210945) is the straightforward one, but it doesn't allow compression. You can use `--format=zip`, but you can't directly unzip that with a pipe command like you can with tar, so you need to save it as a temporary file. Here's a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASENAME=$0

function usage {
    echo "usage: $BASENAME <remote-repo> <file> ..."
    exit 1
}

[ 2 -gt "$#" ] && { usage; }

REPO=$1
shift
FILES=$@

TMPFILE=`mktemp`.zip
git archive -9 --remote=$REPO HEAD $FILES -o $TMPFILE
unzip $TMPFILE
rm $TMPFILE
```

This works with directories too.

Answer (score 1):

**Github Enterprise Solution**

```
HTTPS_DOMAIN=https://git.your-company.com
ORGANISATION=org
REPO_NAME=my-amazing-library
FILE_PATH=path/to/some/file
BRANCH=develop
GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=<your-access-token>

URL="${HTTPS_DOMAIN}/raw/${ORGANISATION}/${REPO_NAME}/${BRANCH}/${FILE_PATH}"

curl -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}" ${URL} > "${FILE_PATH}"
```

Comment: Where do we find the `GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN`?

Comment: You can create a personal access token by going to https://<your-github-server>/settings/tokens and hitting "Generate new token" button.

Comment: Hmm, we have automations that are given a username and password, which are used to authenticate to multiple systems that use the same SSO, so I was hoping for a way to automate generating a token given a username & password.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a file from a specific hash + a remote repository I've tried git-archive and it didn't work.

You would have to use git clone and once the repository is cloned you would have then to use git-archive to make it work.

I post a question about how to do it more simpler in [git archive from a specific hash from remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152200/git-archive-from-a-specific-hash-from-remote)

Answer (score 0):

for bitbucket directly from browser (I used safari...) right-click on 'View Raw" and choose "Download Linked File":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind cloning the entire directory, this small bash/zsh function will have the end result of cloning a single file into your current directory (by cloning the repo into a temp directory and removing it afterwards).

Pro: You only get the file you want

Con: You still have to wait for the whole repo to clone

```
git-single-file () {
        if [ $# -lt 2 ]
        then
                echo "Usage: $0 <repo url> <file path>"
                return
        fi
        TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
        git clone $1 $TEMP_DIR
        cp $TEMP_DIR/$2 .
        rm -rf $TEMP_DIR
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/4653540) may help make sparse clone, that is without overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to *download* the file there's a hassle-free application called `gget`:

```sh
gget github.com/gohugoio/hugo 'hugo_extended_*_Linux-ARM.deb'
```

The above example would download single file from `hugo` repository.

https://github.com/dpb587/gget

Answer (score -1):

Related to @Steven Penny's answer, I also use wget. Furthermore, to decide which file to send the output to I use -O .

If you are using gitlabs another possibility for the url is:

```
wget "https://git.labs.your-server/your-repo/raw/master/<path-to-file>" -O <output-file>
```

Unless you have the certificate or you access from a trusted server for the gitlabs installation you need --no-check-certificate as @Kos said. I prefer that rather than modifying .wgetrc but it depends on your needs.

If it is a big file you might consider using -c option with wget. To be able to continue downloading the file from where you left it if the previous intent failed in the middle.