# git show remote repository (display the contents of a single file)

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to get the contents of a single file from a remote git repository?  "git archive" looks promising, except that GitHub has it explicitly disabled.

The following StackOverflow question generally had the right idea: [Retrieve a single file from a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/git-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository)

In our situation, we're basically looking to do a "git show " except that we'd like to perform that against git://github.com/SomeUser/SomeRepository.

Right now we have a script that simply clones the repository locally and executes "git show" which does the job.  We're looking for a way around the clone.  Simplicity is ideal in this situation rather than availability of the remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

What about parsing the github url?  It looks like you can get the raw contents of a file (using curl, wget etc...) via something like:

```
http://github.com/SomeUser/SomeRepository/raw/CommitId/Path/To/File
```

Comment: Where `CommitId` can be name of branch (but I think currently it cannot be just `HEAD`). Also GitHub has an API.

Comment: Yes, this would work--but only for Github and other providers that provide the source via HTTP.  I was hoping for a more generic solution that just used git.

What we ended up doing was cloning the repository locally and then piping the output of "git show" to a file.