# git equivalent to `svn export` or github workaround

Tags: git, github

I want to fetch a **single file** from a git repository. Using SVN, I can use `svn export` as follows:

```
sudo svn export http://www.example.com/repos/Trunk/pathtofile/file.ext
```

This just downloads the file, naked, i.e without any repository info with it.

Is there an equivalent to `svn export` in git?

The closest I got was "`git show upstream/master:pathtofile/file.ext`" but this isn't really equivalent because you already need to be inside a git repo for it to work.

Another option I have, because I'm using github, is to try to `wget` the github raw file.

```
wget https://raw.github.com/<mygithubuser>/repo/master/pathtofile/file.ext?login=<mylogin>&token=<notsurewhattoputhere>
```

The problem is that the repo is private so I need to supply a token and I'm not sure how to generate this and use it in a `wget`?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/git-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository

Comment: I agree, it's similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121379... but it's not a carbon copy of that question and I couldn't find the solution there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19689284/881551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not checked, but according to [this git hub page](https://github.com/blog/170-token-authentication) your authentication token is supplied on you profile page.  So assuming it's an option to just manually embed it in the command, then I'd go for that.  Otherwise I suppose you'd need to accept it as a parameter to the script this command will be contained in, or possibly in a configuration file.  Although I guess both of those options could have security concerns.

Comment: That github page looked very promising. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get a `wget` working even though I was using the token as specified.

Comment: Odd, that page certainly seems to imply that the token based authentication should work anywhere.  I don't have access to any private repos myself to test anything out myself though.  Did you enclose the URL in quotes when running wget?  Just ask because that's a mistake I commonly make, and I notice they're missing in your example command above.

Comment: Also, have you tried supplying the username & token as POST parameters?  That seems to be what the example from that link does with it's -F parameter to curl

Comment: YES YES YES - It worked when I enclosed the URL in quotes when running wget. I didn't know that was needed. Thanks @obmarg.

Comment: No problem.  It's needed because the shell treats & (and possibly ?) as special characters, so you either need to escape them or enclose the whole parameter in quotes, just as you would if the url contained spaces.

Comment: This is great. Did not know this existed. I have leveraged this to add a more secure answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If the repo is in GitHub then [**just use svn export!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export/19689284#19689284)

`svn export https://github.com/username/repo-name/trunk/pathtofile/file.ext`

Comment: Upvoted for the github svn support link! Not a very widely known fact.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put the token and username in the query string.  Instead do something like this:

```
curl -F 'login=mylogin' -F 'token=mytoken' https://raw.github.com/<mygithubuser>/repo/master/pathtofile/file.ext > /tmp/file.ext
```

As for why you should not put it in the QS [this is a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-a-https-query-string-secure).