# Having trouble downloading Git archive tarballs from Private Repo

Tags: git, github

I need the ability to download our application at specific tags, but I am unable to find a working solution for this. Downloading tarballs based on git tag seems promising but I am unable to get it working using Curl. I have tried the following but all I get back is the source for the github 404 page.

```
curl -sL https://github.com/$ACCOUNT/$PRIVATE_REPO/tarball/0.2.0.257m?login=$MY_USER_NAME&token=$MY_TOKEN > 0.2.0.257m.tar
```

Comment: Have you tried the same URL scheme on a public repo?

Comment: Have you tried wget? Or just use git to clone the code from a specific tag?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For public repo, you have [this gist](https://gist.github.com/758124) listing some examples:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tarball/3.5.5 -O ~/tmp/cake_phpunit/phpunit.tgz
```

For a private repo, try passing your credential information in a post directive:

```
wget --quiet --post-data="login=${login}&token=${token}" --no-check-certificate https://github.com/$ACCOUNT/$PRIVATE_REPO/tarball/0.2.0.257m
```

Or use a curl command as in SO question "[git equivalent to `svn export` or github workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329607/6309)", also explained in great details in:
"[**A curl tutorial using GitHub's API**](https://gist.github.com/2288960)".

---

The [OP Steven Jp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317806/steven-jp) reports having made the `curl` command work:

> The final curl command ended up looking something like this:

```
curl -sL --user "${username}:${password}" https://github.com/$account/$repo/tarball/$tag_name > tarball.tar
```

(in multiple lines for readability)

```
curl -sL --user "${username}:${password}" 
  https://github.com/$account/$repo/tarball/$tag_name
  > tarball.tar
```

Comment: Your second link helped me get things working. the final curl command ended up looking something like this `curl -sL --user "${username}:${password}" https://github.com/$account/$repo/tarball/$tag_name > tarball.tar`

Comment: @Steven_JP Excellent. I have included your command in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Not sure if those wget examples would still work, but this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347134/downloading-a-tarball-from-github-without-curl

Answer (score 18):

After creating an [access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use),

you can use `wget`:

```
wget --output-document=<version>.tar.gz \
    https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/tarball/<version>?access_token=<OAUTH-TOKEN>
```

or `curl`:

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/tarball/<version>?access_token=<OAUTH-TOKEN> \
    > <version>.tar.gz
```

More information can be found in [GitHub's API reference for archive links](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link).

Comment: it might be that you need to add the  '--no-check-certificate' argument:

```wget  --no-check-certificate --output-document=<version>.tar.gz    https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/tarball/<version>?access_token=<OAUTH-TOKEN>```

Comment: This was the one that got me closest. The only difference is that GitHub api now wants the token in the header of the request. Eg. ```curl -L -H "Authorization: token <token>" https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/tarball/<tag> > out.tar.gz```

Comment: As of 2020-02-10 this has been deprecated unfortunately :'( https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/ . removed as of september 8th 2021

Answer (score 1):

Log into your Private Org on Github.com, then go here to create your token: 
https://github.com/settings/applications#personal-access-tokens

When trying to Curl into your Private Org, use the following:

```
curl --header 'Authorization: token ADDACCESSTOKENHERE' \
 --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' \
 --remote-name \
 --location https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/PROJECT/contents/FILE
```

Replace what's in CAPS with your information...

Comment: For some reason, I had issue with sending multiple headers with curl to Github API to download a binary asset, when one header is for auth. It returns XML response of "Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified". But if I changed the auth from being a header to query string parameter, then it works. So just mentioning this quirk.