# Download from github automatically with every commit?

Tags: php, github, git-post-receive

I have a few plugins created using jQuery, I have the demo's located on my server, I want to automatically update the demo every time a change is commited to the master branch on github.

I know I can use [Post-Receive Hooks](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/) to get a buzz on my server, that's easy enough, what I don't know how to do yet is get the PHP script to download the latest version of the entire repository from github?

Is there an API to do this, or is there perhaps a direct link to the always latest version of a repository zipped?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046027/having-trouble-downloading-git-archive-tarballs-from-private-repo

Comment: Hi Joachim Isaksson; can you please add that as an answer?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Please post your comment as an answer, otherwise I shall delete this question shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `/zipball/master` to the end of your project web URL, you will get a zip of the master branch back.

Comment: I think this feature is deprecated, if not already removed. For example, try downloading Kickstrap: https://github.com/ajkochanowicz/Kickstrap/zipball/master

Comment: @ajkochanowicz Kickstrap doesn't have a master branch, but for example `https://github.com/ajkochanowicz/Kickstrap/zipball/stable` works to get the stable branch.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Right. I hope they keep this feature. They recently removed the download button from the UI and I fear they'll eventually get rid of this too as soon as some time passes.