# How to use ssh authentication with github API?

Tags: curl, github, ssh, github-api

Is there some way to use ssh-based authentication when accessing the GitHub API through the command line (via, e.g., curl, etc.?).

<sub>FWIW, I tried many variations of the following (varying the way I specified my public ssh key file) but in every case I was still prompted for my password:</sub>

```
% curl --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub --user yrstruly https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using ssh, then you would never logon as '`yrstruly`'. You would always connect as 'git'.
Your public key would be enough for GitHub to recognize you as '`yrstruly`'.
And since you are using an https address, and not an ssh one, that `--pubkey` option is likely to be ignored.

A valid ssh address would be: `ssh://git@api.github.com`, and I don't think Github proposes that kind of access for its api.

The [`curl --user` option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u) would be necessary for https address only, as in "[Having trouble downloading Git archive tarballs from Private Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10053425/6309)":

```
curl -sL --user "${username}:${password}" https://github.com...
```

Comment: Regarding your last point, there's a ton of commands in the GitHub API that modify a repo, and for which authentication would obviously be necessary.  Furthermore, authentication aside, at least some of these commands *could not possibly work* without a `-u` parameter because they'd be ambiguous.  E.g. where would `curl -u yrstruly -d '{"name":"newrepo"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos` create the new repo "newrepo" if a `-u` parameter was not specified?

Comment: @kjo I agree, -u is necessary and it is what I use in my answer (with username and password). However, I would not use any pubkey, since ssh isn't involved here.

Comment: @VonC Is this still the case in 2018? It's possible to create Deploy Keys which are ssh and presumably intended to be used with the API but I can't work out how

Comment: @MarkAdamson did you try with `curl -u git: --key ~/.ssh/yourKey ...`? But yes, ssh is not accessible from the outside for GitHub.

Comment: @VonC reading around a bit more I realise that Deploy Keys do not give access to the GitHub API, they are just to work with native Git operations