# How do I use SSH to login Github and create a new repository in the command line?

Tags: git, shell, ssh

When I create a new Github repository by using the curl command as shown below, it always asks me to enter the password.

`curl -u "$(git config user.name)" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"$1\"}" | grep -q "Bad credentials"`

Here is my question.  How to use SSH to login Github and create a new repository by using the ssh keychain in the command line?

Comment: See https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks, I read the page and changed the code as `curl -u "Authorization: $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d {\"name\":\"test\"}`, but it returned the massage as: `{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}` 
What did I miss?

Comment: You are calling a github api. It's an HTTP request. It needs a token or a password instead of the public key.

Comment: To generate a token, see https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you for your patience.  I have generated the personal access tokens and still got the `"message": "Bad credentials"`.  So sad.

Comment: If you provide a token, `-u "$(git config user.name)"` is not needed.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you.  Yes, I did erased the `-u "$(git config user.name)"`, and the command become `curl "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN_NUMBERS" https://api.github.com/user/repos/ -d {\"name\":\"test\"}`.  However, the message is shown as `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Comment: `curl -H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN_NUMBERS" ...`. You missed `-H` or `--header`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I also run the `curl -H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN_NUMBERS" ...`.  The `"message": "Not Found"` shows up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219858/discussion-between-elpiekay-and-teenage-programmer).

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you so much.  I knew where I did wrong.  After the `repos`, `/` should not exist.  Therefore, the command should be `curl -H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN_NUMBERS" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d {\"name\":\"test\"}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind the `user.name`/`user.email` config settings have nothing to do with:

- authentication (they are used for commit authorship only)
- your GitHub account (you can set your user.name to be the same as your GitHub account name, but user.name can be anything you want, really)

Bu using a `curl -H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN_NUMBERS"` as recommended by [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay), you bypass completely the need to provide a "user name".
The [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) is enough for GitHub to authenticate you.

Anything with '`ssh`' in it (like `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) would apply only for SSH URL (`git@github.com:<me>/<myRepo>`) and has nothing to do with HTTPS-based `curl` commands.
SSH would not apply to `api.github.com` calls anyway, as [I mentioned in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15047403/6309).