# Downloading a tarball from github without curl

Tags: linux, shell, curl, github, wget

I have an embedded system where I cannot install anything and the only tool I could potentially use to fetch something is wget. It turns out you cannot do the same things with wget that you can with curl. I cannot cross-compile for this system either, so I need to resort to Python or shell scripts. There pure-Python implementation of git called Dulwich actually has some C code that I'd need to cross-compile... So I even resorted looking into that, FYI.

What I need is get code from github repository, and the obvious solution to that is using tarballs they provide. I usually copy the link to download zip button from the repository page and use an authorization token instead of username and password. It works pretty simply with curl like so:

```
curl -L https://<token>@github.com/<org|user>/<repo>/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz
```

Turns out wget is somewhat more awkward and whatever I tried just does work.

Comment: Why can't you cross-compile ?

Comment: Cause I don't have the same toolchain to compile dynamically linked version of curl (or git). If I try to compile a statically linked version of either of the two, it would probably take a good hour to put together from scratch with all the dependencies. And why do I really have to, if full version of wget is there already... And I did have Python too, but using urllib2 would probably be quite tedious and  I'd need to explicitly handle things like redirections and retry...

Comment: The C code in Dulwich is optional. You can use Dulwich without it by building with "setup.py install --pure". The C extensions will improve the performance significantly for larger repositories though.

Comment: Your command really helped, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After beating my head on various combination of wget flags involving either:

- `--post-data`; or
- `--user=` with and without `--pasword=` as well as vice versa; or
- `--header="Authorization: token <token>"`

I looked back at the documentation and found that there are alternative endpoints in [releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release). Looks like firstly I just cannot use the `Authorization` header with the server that hosts tarballs and secondly curl (or github front-end, based on the agent string) seem to be doing a different thing with `<token>@github.com` vs wget's `--user=<token>`, and it's not the most pleasant thing to figure out.

So what works is this:

```
wget \
  --header='Authorization: token <token>' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/<org|user>/<repo>/tarball/<ref>
```