# Difficulty cloning individuality file from github repository

Tags: github, git-clone, angstrom-linux

I'm trying to pull an individual file from a private github repository of mine, and am having difficulties.

Specifically, this works:

```
git clone git@github.com:userName/repositoryName.git
```

but I can't seem to find any documentation in how to clone/get a single file. I've tried a few variations:

```
git clone git@github.com/userName/repositoryName/blob/master/example.py
git clone git@github.com/userName/repositroyName.git/example.py
```

Each time I get prompted for my password:

```
Cloning into 'example.py'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Except upon entering my valid password, I get:

```
ERROR: Repositroy not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Not sure what to do at this point, I'm running Angstrom Linux 3.2.28

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: Retrieve a single file from a repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/git-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository)