# Error: blob is too big - downloading a single zip file from github repo

Tags: github

When downloading a 10 MB zip file from my github (free) repo, I received this error:

Error: blob is too big

... 10 MB doesn't seem that big for a binary download... but in either case, how do you download individual larger binary files from github or how do you set up github so that certain binary files in a project can be downloaded?

Comment: It seems to be a limitation on Github when downloading blob files through the we interface. A solution is to retrieve it by cloning the repo

Comment: this isn't very efficient when the repo is 1gb and you just need the 10mb zip...

Comment: that's true, there are multiple methods to retrieve a specific file without cloning the whole repo : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2466755/1606729  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/git-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository check `git archive`, bare repositories, or the `--depth` option for `git checkout`

Answer (score 1):

Github is doing this intentionally, to prevent project owners from distributing compiled binaries via Github.

They want Github to be a platform for sharing source code, not a platform for sharing files.
It is also [a way to prevent misuse](http://developers.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=3779397&cid=43806415) (distributing non-open movies/etc).

Google Code is unfortunately following their example, and will prevent project owners from uploading new files in a few months.

A solution is to host files on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net) or [similar services](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44562/google-code-downloads-discontinued-what-to-use-instead).