# git archive with LibGit2Sharp

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

Recently I saw both [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/git-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/checkout-only-one-file-from-git) where the answers say you can use `git archive` to retrieve a single file from a remote git repository. This is great, and I would like to be able to emulate that functionality using LibGit2Sharp.

I have looked at [the source code](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/tree/vNext/LibGit2Sharp), but I can't find anything that really does archiving. There's an `ArchiverBase` class, but this seems like it's just meant to be derived from, and I can't see anything that derives from it. `ObjectDatabase` has an `Archive()` method that uses an `ArchiverBase` parameter, but none of the `ArchiverBase` methods are really implemented. Do I need to derive `ArchiverBase` and overwrite its methods myself? How would I go about that? Has it already been done in some other class?

In short, **How can I emulate `git archive` using LibGit2Sharp to retrieve a single file as described in the linked questions?**

Comment: There's a concrete implementation for tar in `TarArchiver`, but you cannot point it to a remote repository, only the local repository.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Could you please promote that comment into an answer so that I can upvote it? ;p

Comment: @wlyles Ed's right. At this moment, you can't do this through LibGit2Sharp through the archiving feature. You'll have to Clone() the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does happen to be a concrete archiver implementation in LibGit2Sharp, [`TarArchiver`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/TarArchiver.cs), which will create a tar archive of your local Git repository.  However, it will only work against a repository, it will not work against a remote endpoint, so it will not be suitable to retrieve a single file like `git archive` can.

LibGit2Sharp does not include a way to do what you are asking.  Your options are to:

1. Clone the repository, checking out a single file
2. Use an API offered by your Git hosting provider (OctoKit for GitHub or the REST API for Team Foundation Server) to retrieve a single file.
3. Execute `git-archive` yourself.