# Pull one file from Git without having to clone the entire repository

Tags: git

I have a Git repository named "test" inside which I have four files and sub-directory named "test2".

So the path would be **/test2/file.txt**

I would like to pull (remotely) just the sub-directory with all of its content (/test2/file.txt) without cloning "test". Is this possible?

Comment: No, it isn’t possible.

Comment: It's not clear your usage of git terminology is exactly correct.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish `git checkout` may work, or if you have access to the remote directly `git archive`

Comment: Andrew C git archive worked when remotely accessed...thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
git clone $URL
```

you could use

```
git archive --remote=$URL master test2 -o test2.zip
```

which would create a zip file containing the content of the test2 folder of the remote master branch.

Comment: Your comment really helped me, thanks!

Comment: Additional details can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18331440/180538