# Bitbucket download stopping at 1Gb

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to download a zipped version of the source files (not clone, but using the actual download button from the dashboard) from Bitbucket.

The repo is around 5Gb in size (it's hosted in house here not using the cloud so soft and hard limit do not apply), but at the 1Gb mark on the download bar it stops with no reason. This zip is then unopenable.

Is there a config option in Bitbucket somewhere that I have to increase? I have not found any topic relating to this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Download button, that means you are using some Bitbucket add-on. You can ask vendor to look into that. In mean time you can use Git archive command to download file. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive 
look at this answer too. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository)

Comment: Yes, I thought it was a standard feature of Atlassian but your right it's an add-on.