# How to copy full source without opening raw(bitbucket)

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

Is there any shortcut available to copy entire source code from a `bitbucket file` without selecting view `raw file option`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and [archive the remote repo for one file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512140/6309), using [`git archive --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).

```
git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md | tar -xO
```

Comment: is there any shortcuts available for browser??

Comment: @Abhilash Not that I know of.