# PowerShell - downloads TXT file with WRONG content using the REST API

Tags: powershell, api, rest

I have a file which I download using the REST API.
Just to emphasize that I tried with both commands: `Invoke-RestMethod` and `Invoke-WebRequest`

```
$uri = "https://bitbucket.org.dev/projects/TEST/repos/fa/browse/Packages/ATS.txt"
$API_KEY="ZTU2MT"
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{Authorization=$("Basic {0}" -f $API_KEY)} -Uri $uri  -OutFile ATS.txt
```

If I access that URI in browser file or download it manually file can be viewd without any issue in clear way.

This is the content of the file (its begining)

```
#
# exported extension module.
# source          ""
# timestamp (utc) "2020-03-30 12:06:23.3"
# ***** DO NOT EDIT! *****
```

But download file looks completely different (like it is in HTML format)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-..."
```

Also I have some zip file which needs to be downloaded as well, but with it also I am getting invalid file which cannot be extracted (opened)

Answer (score 1):

As written in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7), `Invoke-WebRequest` returns an object of type `BasicHtmlWebResponseObject`.

You need to select the `Content` property to get the text you are looking for.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{Authorization=$("Basic {0}" -f $API_KEY)} -Uri $uri | Select-Object -Expand Content | Out-File -FilePath c:\somefile.txt
```

**Update:**

Check this post to find more info about downloading files from a private repository in BitBucket.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222671/13440610

Comment: thanks for you assistance - but I am still getting the exactly same HTML format in my downloaded file with your command.. Do you know what can be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Can you post more of the html you are getting? Check also the response code. If there is an error, itmight be related to Authorization.

Comment: Thanks. <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><title>Source of AccountingATS.txt - FA-Select - BitBucket</title><script>
window.WRM=window.WRM||{};window.WRM._unparsedData=window.WRM._unparsedData||{};window.WRM._unparsedErrors=window.WRM._unparsedErrors||{};
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-plugin:context-path.context-path"]="\u0022\u0022";
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-webpack-INTERNAL:date-format-preference.data"]="\u0022\u0022";...

Comment: I can for example without any issue, so that is why I thought it is not related to authorization - get a list of all folders and files in repository using the REST API. But not sure why I cannot retrieve the file itself.

Comment: updated the answer. I think this is related to Bitbucket. You have a full example in the link.

Comment: I am already encoding my credentials and they are passed since I succeed to retrieve some other artifacts. But on linked answer they are mentioned something that I should have my account inside the URL??? Did you also understood like that? 

"https://bitbucket.org/<account>/<repo_name>/get/<branch_or_tag_or_whatever>.zip"

But how I should put my account here? I really do not understand what should be the URL syntax? As stated: with my URLs I can assess manually to my files but I do not have my account within the URL.
Thanks...

Comment: Hi. I added ?raw suffix at the end ant then it worked. It worked for txt but not for zip file so I switched back to my Invoke method (Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{Authorization=$("Basic {0}" -f $API_KEY)} -Uri $uri  -OutFile ATS.txt?raw) and then it worked for both formats...