# fatal: repository 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emmetio/emmet/master/lib/snippets.json/' not found

Tags: url, wget, git-clone

For the same url,wget can get it ,git clone can't.

```
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emmetio/emmet/master/lib/snippets.json"
wget $url
```

An error occur when to get with git clone.

```
git clone $url
Cloning into 'snippets.json'...
fatal: repository 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emmetio/emmet/master/lib/snippets.json/' not found
```

Same errors for both
`url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emmetio/emmet/master/lib/snippets.json"`
and
`url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emmetio/emmet/master/lib/snippets.json/"`.

Comment: error because have a forward dash after `snippets.json`

Comment: i think `git clone` just for get whole repository, not for a single file. Try this `git archive --remote=git://git.foo.com/project.git HEAD:path/to/directory filename | tar -x`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1125476/6309