# how to use JGit api to realize git command:"git checkout commit_id" by commit_id

Tags: java, git, jgit

Coding of my company has such requirement : You need create a new folder to save your committed code when you complete this task.
So how to use JGit api to realize the following git command...
        **git checkout commit_id**

Comment: Thank you,But l just want to checkout  it  to a new folder not to this repository

Comment: The `CheckoutCommand` will always write to the working directory of the repository, just as `git checkout <commit-id>` would do. Please re-phrase your question if you look for something different.

Comment: The command ："git checkout commit_id" .what l want to checkout is commited files not the whole project in that commit.Sir,do you have any solution

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619755/how-to-clone-a-single-file-with-jgit shows how to get the contents of a single file revision. Further information about accessing Git objects with JGit can be found here: https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/10/20/git-internals/. Alternatively, you can specify the file to be checked out with `CheckoutCommand::addPath`.

Comment: Thanks for your help，sir.My company ask me to copy committed files by commitedid with Java language.My idea is get commited files by comaring two commitId to get filenames.Then copy these files from local repository to a new folder by io.Now l can get filenames,l will complete the coding at tomorrow.