# Download single file from private Git repository in declarative Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I already had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository), but I wonder how I can securely download a single from a private Git repository in a declarative pipeline, preferably using a credentials ID or similar.

I assume I have to use something like:

```
sh 'git archive ... || tar --extract'
```

Answer (score 2):

for this purpose there is a ssh agent plugin that can be used within the pipeline script:

```
sshagent(credentials: ['credentials-id']) {
  sh "git archive --remote=${git_repository_url} --format=tar ${branch_name} ${path_to_file} | tar xf -"
}
```

Note: `path_to_file` can be either the path to a file, or just the filename

Comment: Somehow my credentials ID doesn't work with the `sshagent` step, whereas it works fine when I perform a clone with the [`git`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/) step. Also, when I use the snippet generator, I see the correct credentials ID in the dropdown menu of the Git plugin, but not in the SSH Agent plugin. Any ideas? (BTW: Would you mind adding a [link to the plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/)?)