# Checking file version for files in git repository without downloading them

Tags: linux, bash, git, curl, wget

I need to prepare job on linux that will download some files from two git repositories and make some operations on them. So let say that I want to download those files:

https://gitlab.com/repository_1/dir_1/file_11

https://gitlab.com/repository_1/dir_2/file_12

https://gitlab.com/repository_2/dir_1/file_21

I don't want to download whole repos (as they are big). I know that I may use wget, but maybe it is possible to do it with git (it may help in next step described below). I tried to use

```
git checkout origin/master -- https://gitlab.com/repository_2/dir_1/file_21
```

but I get error log:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/fpwork)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

After downloading those files won't be deleted so I also want to be sure, that in next run those files will be in latest version (after some time files on disk may  be outdated). If they not I need to get updated files (delete and download again?). I may delete local files and download them again each time, but I think that there are better ways to have actual files.

I tried to use this command to get file's md5sum:

```
curl -sL https://gitlab.com/repository/dir/file | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

and compare it with already downloaded file, but each time I run this command I get different md5sum.

Some of those files are archives, so `git diff` won't work.

Summarising:

1. How to download single files from git repository?
2. How to check if downloaded file is in latest version?

============================

Ad1. Downloading could be done with:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://gitlab.com/repository_1.git HEAD dir_1/file_11 | tar -x
```

Be aware that using https instead of ssh will cause `fatal: Operation not supported by protocol.` error.

Ad2. this wget command works for me well:

```
wget -r -N -c https://gitlab.com/repository_1/dir_1/file_11
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve a single file from a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I get:
fatal: Operation not supported by protocol.

Comment: @MarcnB Instead of answering in a comment, you should [edit] your question and show the command that you tried together with the error message **in the question*. This allows everyone to see in one place what you already tried.

Comment: Above error was caused by using https. Using ssh and git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md | tar -x works.