# Is there a simple way to get a JSON file from a Git repository using Node js?

Tags: node.js, git

I am currently making an electron application with Node js. I have several JSon files in a git repository. What I want to be able to do is get those files from the repository, and then put them in the C drive on the local machine using Node js. I have tried curlreqest, but what I want to do is be able to get specific files without actually having to clone the entire repository. Or if I need to clone the entire repository is there a simple way to do so and then access the files I need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18331440/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+get+single+file