# Checkout a single file with credentials in one line in cmd

Tags: git, command-line

I am using Gitea and currently trying to use the command line to checkout a single file using this

git archive --remote=git://gitea.server.com/project.git HEAD:path/to/directory filename | tar -x

from [Retrieve a single file from a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository/5324532#5324532)

But I am not able to include the credentials in order to work.

I have tried two combinations with my username and its generated access token

--remote=git://username:token@gitea.server.com/project.git

--remote=username:token@gitea.server.com/project.git

But it never works.

How can I include the user credentials in order to checkout a single file in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git://` refers to the `git` protocol (typically found on port 9418).  This protocol is unauthenticated: it has no capability to provide a user name, much less any security information *about* that user name.  If you have a server that serves such a port, every file in every repository served by this server is completely open to everyone.  There's no *need* for a user name and token, and you wouldn't provide one.

The syntax `username:token@host.name/path/to/repo.git` is shorthand for `ssh://username:token@host.name/path/to/repo.git` and hence uses the ssh protocol.  Ssh doesn't take passwords or tokens here so `username:token` is the whole user name.  (Colons are allowed after the `@` and specify the ssh *port*, in place of the default 22.)

To use https, which is where you *would* use a user name and token, use `https://username:token@host.name/path/to.repo.git`.  The `https://` part is not optional.

Comment: This worked to a certain degree in the sense that it is the solution to my problem. My other problem is my gitea apparently is not compatible with `git archive` since it throws back `fatal: operation not supported by protocol` but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: That particular error seems odd, but I've never set up a Gitea server so I don't know where to start looking for that.