# XML file with imbedded image data or ZIP file with XML + separate image files

Tags: xml, serialization

I need to make a file format for my software. The data is basic key/value pairs and images. The options are:

1) One XML file that has CDATA tag with binary encoded image files or image files encoded in a RGBRGBRGB or RGBARGBARGBA format.

2) One XML file holding key/value pairs and links to image files. These image files would be packaged with the XML file in a ZIP or TAR

What do you think is the best approach? If either is ok, which one do you think is easier to implement? I am using wxwidgets and the wxImage class has a getData() function that returns an array in RGB format. Would writing this array to XML be easier than base 64 encoding a jpeg/png etc? I've never programatically handled a ZIP file but I know there is a helper class in wxwidgets for this kind of thing.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: This might be interesting if you need to store the result under version control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320654/will-subversion-efficiently-store-openxml-office-documents/1321654

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Open Packaging Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) and the Open XML SDK<sup>1</sup> as suggested by Nestor would be one option but you could also easily roll your own version of such a format.

In general I would prefer the zipped option as the file size would be significant smaller. XML can be compressed very well and the images won't be expanded.

When using a single XML file with embedded images you would have to use base64 encoding to save your images. The size of the encoded images will be about [1.37 times larger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) than the original size.

However, a single XML file might have advantages regarding further processing of the document, for example you can use it without additional unzip directly as input document for an XSL transform.

<sup>1</sup>The OpenXML format is a good example in this matter. Normally, files are stored in a zip package fulfilling the Open Packaging Conventions. However, there is also a single XML file version available, the [so-called Flat OPC format](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/the-flat-opc-format.aspx) (at least in Word 2007) to be used as input/output format for XSLT and other document processing steps.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Open XML Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456487.aspx) instead of creating your own? Open XML is what Office 2007 uses for their files (Excel, Word, Powerpoint, etc) and it's basically 2).