# Is there any way to export the diff of a MS word document as a patch file?

Tags: svn, ms-word, tortoisesvn, diff, patch

TortoiseSVN allows you to view changes to MS word documents via some clever VB scripting (I think). If you try and make a patch file though, you get:

```
Index: MyDocument.docx
===================================================================
Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.
svn:mime-type = application/octet-stream
```

Is there any way to create a patch file of the changes which the VBA script could understand?

Comment: This would be really interesting if it were possible, but patching a DOCX file is like asking for a way to diff a ZIP file in a meaningful way. I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I just figured that if the VB script was capable of displaying the changes maybe someone knew a way to transport the information in a meaningful way.

Comment: Interestingly, a DOCX file actually IS a ZIP file. I found some more on a similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320654/will-subversion-efficiently-store-openxml-office-documents

Comment: Another relevent post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810/is-version-control-ie-subversion-applicable-in-document-tracking#29837 ...not sure how I missed those two!

Comment: That's why I said it would be like diffing a ZIP file :-)