# SVN: how to setup on godaddy host?

Tags: php, svn

I'm new to SVN, can some one put me on right track of learning more about SVN ?

I hiered a web designer who requested that i setup an (S.V.N) for us to sync work

***My questions is :***

1. What is SVN, and will it realy helpfull to sync our work together ?
2. How can i set it up ? and what are the requirements ?

My website is located on Godaddy server, can i set it up on it ?

thanks a million

Comment: it would seem to be that YOU CAN now put svn on godaddy ?  Looking here ... https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-and-use-svn-on-centos-6-12342

Answer (score 1):

About SVN:

- [What Is Subversion?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.intro.whatis.html)
- [Basic SVN Commands](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html)

It does not seem to be allowed on GoDaddy. Read following

- [Subversion on GoDaddy shared hosting](http://erikfantasia.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/subversion-on-godaddy-shared-hosting/)
- [Install subversion repositories in my GoDaddy Shared hosting account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705821/install-subversion-repositories-in-my-godaddy-shared-hosting-account)