# Git in excel or numbers

Tags: excel, git

I am new in Git, it really help me in my code projects. I have some numbers files (similar to Excel) I am not sure if it is a good idea to keep track of changes with git. I understand that git cannot see what is different in each file but can detect if there is something different (more or less bytes) For me it can be useful to safe the file when I want and write a title in the commit to remember what I have changed. Is git a good option in those cases?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126239/git-or-subversion-for-binary-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, committing binary files in git is not the best thing to do. 
But when you want to track it, that's sometimes the thing to do.

Here, Libreoffice is quite better than Microsoft office because they have "flat" format where all the saved file is just a XML file which is much more source control friendly!

But with Excel,  you also have the solution to use a converter to be able to diff the file in a human friendly way. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106035/717372

Comment: Is there any option with Apple Numbers?

Comment: I don't know apple products (and they are shitly named, so impossible to search). I found for 'keynote' files only : https://github.com/robertoaloi/keynote-to-text