# Is it possible to download a large file outside of repository on `git clone`?

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, github, cordova-plugins

I am developing a Cordova plugin that depends on a large binary file (a custom ios framework) which can be larger than 300MB. That is too large to check into our git repository and I dont think that would be the right solution anyway.

However, I want the binary file to be there when user of the plugin first install it via Cordova command line:

```
cordova plugin install https://path.to.the.plugin.on.github
```

Cordova will automatically clone the git repository. What I am wondering is how to automatically download the binary file from another source such as S3 and place it in the correct location? Is this not possible?

Comment: can't it execute "after install" commands? this way you can have a script to handle the download.

Comment: pretty sure cordova does not have such "after install" hook, but I will checkc again. If you know, please put as answer, because that would definitely solve my problem

Comment: I've never used it before, but [Git Annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) is supposed to help you manage large files with Git somehow, so maybe that might be worth checking out.

Comment: @Cupcake I think Git Annex requires configuring each repo to sync data which really defeats the purpose in this case. I am looking for a technique that needs 0 configuration when the repo gets cloned. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Related discussions on big binary files & git: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161588/git-analog-to-hgs-bigfiles-extension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888604/git-with-large-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am wondering is how to automatically download the binary file from another source such as S3 and place it in the correct location?

Not through git itself.
You could set up a post-checkout hook in order to take care of that step, but a hook isn't propagated through `git push/pull`.

It is easier to store a script (in that git repo) that the user of that repo can call on demand in order to download/update that binary.

Comment: thanks for your answer @VonC. that is the conclusion I came to as well, to add a shell script to download the file using `curl`