# does github support version history for pdf files?

Tags: github

Many papers are archived in [Arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/). A lot of them might also have version histories. But it seems we can't get the update information for one paper when it is updated. Does github support the version history for pdf files? Maybe github can provide the version control for [Arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does GitHub support the version history for pdf files?

Not directly, in that [it cannot display diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971038/6309).
You would [need an external diff](https://gist.github.com/thbar/4943276) like [**`diffpdf`**](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html) for that.

> Maybe github can provide the version control for Arxiv.org.

Right now, GitHub is not used by Arxiv.org. Their ["new" page](http://arxiv.org/new) mentions in 2008:

> We have implemented version control for papers submitted prior to November 1997 in the same way as for papers submitted later.

In 2011:

> [Bulk data available on Amazon S3](http://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data_s3): The bulk data available for download from Amazon S3 has been extended to include both PDF and source files of the latest versions of all arXiv articles.

Comment: Thank you very much for these detail answers! I'm looking forward to that arxiv.org can provide some update notifications like those in github's code repository. Maybe google's scholar alert also can provide this functionality. Google Scholar alerts provide a very convenient way to follow papers. Maybe it can also provide the version update information for the papers. When it is searching the website(arxiv.org), it can compare the latest modified version to the cached version in its own database, and resend the alert to us.

Comment: @mining in the meantime, web services like https://distill.io can help monitoring changes to a given page.

Comment: thanks! The link is very helpful! It can also provide some tracking for some authors's personal webpage with a more flexible way! I also find it can provide a Google Chrome extension, that's very useful! [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/distill-web-monitor/inlikjemeeknofckkjolnjbpehgadgge?hl=en]