# Does git send entire lines in commits?

Tags: git

I have a binary file that I'm forcing git to view as a text file. When I make a change, the entire line is shown in the diff.

If I have a line that is 100mb, and I change 1 byte, is git smart enough to only send the 1 byte difference? Or will it send the entire 100mb line?

Comment: have you looked at these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697216/is-git-good-with-binary-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Merges and diff of binary files are usually a pain with git. I would suggest using a good [binary-to-text-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) scheme. If you have the time to spare it is worth looking into.