# Game development with multiple people in Unity3D: How could we work on the same project simultaneously?

Tags: github, unity-game-engine

First of all, we're all beginners, so I am really sorry if this is a trivial question.

We're developing a game in Unity3D. We have two programmers, and one artist. We'd like to make our life easier by not just simply communicating via Facebook and sending our stuff back and forth. I know about GitHub, but I have a couple of problems with it.

1. It's not free for closed source projects - which would be ideal. Is there an alternative? Is this even the right kind of site to use?
2. Stupid reason, but I just can't comprehend how it works/how to use it. Is there an easy tutorial for it or something?
3. Is it even 'compatible' with Unity3D? Since I don't really know how
   GitHub works, this might also be a really stupid question.

Comment: Version control and unity3d can be a bit of a pain, but you should still definitely use it (version control for multiple developers is really a must, once you have used it you think you are insane for not having always done that).  Most places are going to charge for private projects, gotta make money somehow. Since you're beginners, I suggest you make it public. I doubt anyone will notice or care about your code, then you can make it private if it starts becoming good enough to share.

Comment: Source control in Visual Studio

Comment: Use Git (always!), use Textual format for scenes (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextualSceneFormat.html) and DO NOT EDIT the same scene at the same time! (The best technology to achieve this, is communication: "Hey team, someone is working on this scene? I will take it ")

Comment: Git is a protocol and that can be use with many version controls Like GitHub, Bitbucket,..). BitBucket also  offer you private code repository. if you want to learn about GitHub then this the perfect tutorial of udactiy. https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775

Comment: Git is a protocol and that can be use with many version controls Like GitHub, Bitbucket,..). BitBucket also  offer you private code repository. if you want to learn about GitHub then this the perfect tutorial of udactiy. https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use Bitbucket to host your stuff. Its like github without the open source community.I'm using it on a similar project I'm working on with some guys. It's important you understand that git is version control software developed by Linus Torvalds (creator of the Linux kernel). Git can be used to "commit" changes to a project. Then your other coder could grab those code(script in unity?) files and load them into him project. It is kind of overwhelming to learn to use at first, but it gets easy once you get it. Really learning to use git is one of the best things you can do for yourself.
 As far as using git goes, I use linux so I can just 'man git' to look at commands and then use said commands in the shell. Mac uses bash so it probably is run right from the shell there too. Honestly I don't know at all for windows.
Here are a couple of resources:
https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TI3yVcSahzk

If I had more time I would look for a really good one for you, but I'm going to be late for work!

Answer (score 1):

I have developed some Unity3D projects using GitHub before. So to answer question 3 and the last part of 1 first, yes Unity projects use a file-system architecture that is perfectly compatible with GitHub and once your used to it it is a great tool for team development.

Answer for question 1:
GitHub is just a name brand for a centralized version control system and there are other brands out there with similar offerings such as bit bucket. Google this term for more info. also look into distributed version control as well.

In all honesty though, if your new to developing, the product you will be making will most likely not be of much interest to other people on GitHub and your public repository will probably go unnoticed. If you believe that what you are creating is of such great value it needs to be kept secret, then investing a few dollars a month in a premium service is recommended anyway.

For other options, one would be to [set up a central Git repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) on a server (or one of your home computers) that you or one of you project mates is running. This might be a more complicated method but you would learn a lot of other useful things along the way.

Answer for question 2: 
See -https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/- for github's intro tutorial. Also Youtube has some decent offering if you search for how to use Git Hub.

It can be a little daunting to work with something new and attempt to understand the documentation. If you are planning on getting serious about development though, especially in a corporate setting, you need to learn GIT and practice reading and understanding documentation.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `git` for just about any text-based version control. If the files are binary heavy, it still works but [it's not git's strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697216/is-git-good-with-binary-files).

Until you get the central hosting worked out, you can use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) to [share the changes offline](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/offline-repository-sync-using-git-bundle.html).