# Video files in Git/Codecommit

Tags: git, web-applications, version-control, aws-codecommit

I am building an application with few video backgrounds in some pages. I use aws codecommit. Is it a good practice to push these video file to the remote repo? What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1):

Git does not handle binary files well, so it may not be a good idea to push these files to the repository.  The problem is that Git can have a hard time computing a *diff* for these binaries.  This means that even making a very small change to any of your video files could result in Git thinking that the diff is the entire file.  If the videos are large, then this could have a negative impact on the size of your repository.  In the worst case, checking out your repository would mean checking out *every* version of *each* video file.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697216/is-git-good-with-binary-files) for more information.