# GitHub small binary files

Tags: git, github

I have a github project where my application manages data in binary files.
I want to have git automatically add these files in each commit and replace using the local version.
All my binary files have a unique file extension that I specify and range from 60bytes to 10kb

How can I specify this behavior if possible?

**edit 1:**

I have two computers with git and have the same repository. I push my commits from one computer and the changelog shows that everything uploaded properly except my binary files. I used git pull on my second computer and both say that they are up-to-date however my binary files are not the same across these two devices

**edit 2:**

Comment: Git can handle binary files, add and commit them as normal. Is there something specific you're looking for? Maybe the answers to ["Is Git good with binary files?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697216/is-git-good-with-binary-files) will help.

Comment: "I want to have git automatically add these files in each commit and replace using the local version." Do the files change often?

Comment: yes. the files change often enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I compare the files online and it turns out that git was working perfectly. It turns out that i need to update my gradle settings as i was reading a cached version of the file

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `git add .` from the root folder before doing my git commit command. This ensures that everything that was modified gets committed to your local repo. *Note that I used a period there; the dot*

Comment: but git can't tell if a binary file has been modified

Comment: @DreadMoirai, If it isn't modified, why do you care? If it is modified, this command will add it.

Comment: @DreadMoirai Git can tell if a binary file has been modified. Providing a sensible diff is harder, but possible. Are you seeing behavior that makes you say it can't?

Comment: The question is asking because i don't know how to add such behavior

Comment: @DreadMoirai, See Schwern's comment. By default, git is perfectly capable of capturing changes in binary files. If it doesn't for you, I'd recommend looking at your git configuration files.

Comment: @DreadMoirai, git commit won't commit anything that hasn't been staged. One would use the git add command to stage something and then git commit will commit it to your local repo.

Comment: i use the `git add .` and it tells me that there's nothing to commit

Answer (score 0):

> but git can't tell if a binary file has been modified

If you have a binary file with a specific extension which is ignored by Git when it changes... check if it is not ignored.

```
git check-ignore -v -- my-binary-file
```

If it is ignored from an IDE, check if they have not their own `.gitignore` list.