# Considered "some.dll", but it didn't exist

Tags: c#, git, azure, .net-core

I'm trying to deploy a project that references a local assembly on my hard drive to azure. The project builds and runs locally, however, When I try to deploy it to azure using the command below

```
git push int-live master:master
```

it returns the following error:

```
Error - Changes committed to the remote repository but deployment to website failed.

going through the logs 
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'some' does not exist in the namespace 'comp.utils'

Considered "some.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

This leads me to believe that it's not attaching my assembly in the git repo but I don't know how to make this work and as such any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your DLL "some.dll" is on git history? do you tried to add with: `git add path/to/some.dll`?

Comment: @Leo Thank you for helping me, I didn't realise the dll had to live in the repo. It seems obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As see in comments the `some.dll` is not pushed to live server because is not tracked by git, witch is causing the CS0234, so you just need to add it:

```
git add path/to/some.dll
```

Also, because the DLL is a binary I also recommend that you read the answers here: [Is git good with binary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697216/is-git-good-with-binary-files)

And the `git-lfs` extension can be interesting: https://git-lfs.github.com/