# Are remote branches cloned to local git repo?

Tags: git-branch, git-clone, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partial clone with Git and Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial)

If I only want to clone one branch, how can I do that?

**Does `git clone url` mean `git clone url --all`?**

```
[hugemeow@home base]$ git branch
* master
[hugemeow@home base]$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/donut-release
  remotes/origin/donut-release2
  remotes/origin/eclair-passion-release
  remotes/origin/eclair-release
  remotes/origin/eclair-sholes-release
  remotes/origin/eclair-sholes-release2
  remotes/origin/froyo
  remotes/origin/froyo-release
  remotes/origin/gingerbread
  remotes/origin/gingerbread-mr4-release
  remotes/origin/gingerbread-release
  remotes/origin/ics-factoryrom-2-release
  remotes/origin/ics-mr0
  remotes/origin/ics-mr0-release
  remotes/origin/ics-mr1
  remotes/origin/ics-mr1-release
  remotes/origin/ics-plus-aosp
  remotes/origin/jb-dev
  remotes/origin/jb-mr0-release
  remotes/origin/jb-release
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/tools_r20



[mirror@home base]$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/donut-release
  origin/donut-release2
  origin/eclair-passion-release
  origin/eclair-release
  origin/eclair-sholes-release
  origin/eclair-sholes-release2
  origin/froyo
  origin/froyo-release
  origin/gingerbread
  origin/gingerbread-mr4-release
  origin/gingerbread-release
  origin/ics-factoryrom-2-release
  origin/ics-mr0
  origin/ics-mr0-release
  origin/ics-mr1
  origin/ics-mr1-release
  origin/ics-plus-aosp
  origin/jb-dev
  origin/jb-mr0-release
  origin/jb-release
  origin/master
  origin/tools_r20
```

**Edit 1**
In fact my issue is not the same as [Clone only one branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811434/git-clone-only-one-branch), though the answer may be a bit similar ...

By the way, if that link is the solution, how can I get the list of branches before I cloned it from the remote repo?  (This issue is not mentioned in that link, and if that link could answer my question, this issue should be pre-solved.)

Comment: in fact my issue is not the same as his, though the answer maybe a bit similar...  by the way, if that link is the solution, how can i get the list of branches before i cloned it from remote repo?  see edit 1:)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of branches before clone with [`git ls-remote --heads <repo-url>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote).

Comment: why git Tab only autocomplete for subcommand such as clone , push , etc, but not ls-remote?