# Why is the size of the forked repository so huge in GitHub?

Tags: github, wireshark

I am a newbie to [github](http://github.com/) and I am required to have an understanding of [wireshark](http://github.com/avsej/wireshark) by analyzing its source code. The source code is apparently around **23 MB** but if I try to do a git clone from the link provided in the website, it turns out to be around **636 MB**.

Can someone please shed some light as to why the clone is so big compared to the source code?

Answer (score 9):

When you clone a repository with `git` ... that's what you're doing; cloning a *repository*. You're getting all the branches and their histories, not just `master`.

If you really wanted to, you could just get `master` (or a specific branch) - see: [Clone only one branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811434/git-clone-only-one-branch)

Comment: +1. And even if there was only one branch, you get the whole history of the sources, and not just the latest version.

Comment: @JBNizet - tru dat, I'll add to my answer

Comment: for those looking for a most recent version, you can use shallow cloning - only clone the last x commits https://www.perforce.com/blog/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones - alternatively, download the _source code_, not the _repository_