# How do I "undo" a --single-branch clone?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo using the

`git clone -b <branch name> --single-branch <github url> <target directory>`

This cloned ONLY this branch, but now I want to switch to the master and other branches.  Is there any way besides clearing it out and starting over to clone the rest of the repo that I can undo the --single-branch preference?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

You can tell Git to pull all branches like this:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch origin
```

If you look in `.git/config`, it'll look something like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/owner/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    rebase = true
```

I compared this to a full clone, and saw that the only difference was the "fetch" under `[remote "origin"]`.

Note: I'm running Git version 1.8.2. The config options may have changed if you're running an older version of Git. If my commands don't work, then I'd recommend looking through `.git/config` to see if you can see something similar.

Comment: Just wanted to offer you a special thanks because I did a heck of a lot of reading and googling and wasn't able to come across anything like this.

Comment: Glad to help. The `git` command line tool is incredibly powerful (in fact, most of the commands are implemented in terms of other commands), so you can do a whole lot of stuff with it once you understand how the repository is laid out (basically how the `.git` folder works).

Comment: This didn't work for me - after running these commands `git show-ref tags` still fails.

Comment: Note that this solution will also work if a branch was shallow cloned using the following syntax as well, which experiences the same shortcoming described by OP: `git clone --depth=1 --branch branchname git@github.com:foobar/repo.git destinationpath`

Comment: Wow, this is far from intuitive! It's odd Git doesn't readily have a command to accomplish this. Yeah I got it working... and now I know about the config file int he .git directory too!

Comment: I was able to do this without manually changing the config: `git remote set-branches --add origin '*'` and then `git fetch`.

Answer (score 96):

If you want to add a single branch, you can do the following:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin [remote-branch]
git fetch origin [remote-branch]:[local-branch]
```

Works with git version 1.9.1

Comment: This adds multiple `fetch =` lines to .git/config, very handy when you want to switch between two branches on the remote but not fetch a whole bunch of other branches.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 26):

**To add another remote branch** to my local repository that was cloned using `--single-branch`, the following works for me:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin [remote-branch]
git fetch
git checkout [remote-branch]
```

You can also use wildcards for `[remote-branch]`, e.g.

```
git remote set-branches --add origin release-1.*
git fetch
git checkout release-1.5
```

**This works using git version 2.21.1**. Other answers suggesting to do `git fetch origin [remote-branch]:[local-branch]` did not work as it creates the local branch in an untracked state. When running `git pull` it first tried to merge all the commits of the remote branch to my local one once again.

Comment: second time i come back to this answer. very useful. thanks!

Comment: The most useful answer

Comment: I've been here several times xd

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 8):

For me worked:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://*<yourPath>*.git
git fetch
```

Comment: Easiest solution without messing with `git config`.

Comment: This should also be an accepted answer. Works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Just add the original repo as a new remote, and work off of there?

```
git remote add path/to/myrepo myNewOrigin
git fetch myNewOrigin
```

You can even delete your current 'origin' remote and rename 'myNewOrigin' to 'origin' if you would want to.

From there you can pull/merge/rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `.git/config` file of your local repo, line `fetch` of `[remote origin] section`.

Before something like this

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/owner/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

After it will be so

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/owner/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially applied Dominik Pawlak's answer and it worked. But I wasn't able to pull any further changes, after I committed more code into my new branch.

There is another way of resetting `single-branch` entirely, which hasn't been mentioned here:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:{yourProject}/{yourRepo}.git
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/{yourBranch}  {yourBranch}
git pull
```

This resets everything to the original.