# Git: how to change the branch of the origin my local is pointed to?

Tags: git

I have 2 repos: one is the official (where I pull off) and the second is customized (where I push to).

I've used the technique described here: [Git push existing repo to a new and different remote repo server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server)
to make the connections with these 2 repos.

Now I have a problem - I primary cloned the official repo from a branch, not from a master. Now, when the official branch has merged with the master on the remote repo, I want my local to pull from the master too, not from that branch.

How to do that?

My origin is called official (to pull off).

Comment: `checkout` to `master` and pull?

Comment: try this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb how to do that taking into account my local repo is connected with 2 remotes?

Comment: Your question has a bunch of terminology issues: for instance, in Git, you cannot "clone from a branch". Git does not define *an* origin, but does use the word `origin` as the default first name for what Git calls a *remote*. A remote is, essentially, a short name for a URL. Whoever answers the "phone call" (the request for service) at that URL should be a Git repository, so a remote like `origin` is a short name for "how to call up another Git". Unfortunately, Git is full of specialized terminology, and to use it well, you'll need to memorize a lot of this kind of silliness...

Comment: @torek Really? Wow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git

Comment: That's cloning a specified branch *from* a *repository*, not "cloning from a branch". Had you said "ran `git clone --single-branch`", I could have pointed you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714159/how-do-i-undo-a-single-branch-clone

Comment: @torek everyone except you understood me. Of course, I clone from a repo, but there is no need to mention it because it's obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just checkout to master

```
git checkout master
```

Then, pull from the required remote, `official` in your case

```
git pull official master
```

Comment: Exactly. As for a first command I did *git checkout -b master*, is that the same? Thanks!!

Comment: That's used to create a new branch named master. It's usually always present and will throw a fatal error. But in your case you cloned a non-master branch initially. So you'll need to create one. It should be fine.

Comment: looks like I accidentally did what I had to :-0