# Shallow clone cannot fetch new commits/branches?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-checkout

I have this:

```
git clone --depth=1 <repo> app
cd app
git fetch origin
git checkout a119b1076dd45a88a3609c4f7893ef3d82f9a4ee
```

but it says:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: a119b1076dd45a88a3609c4f7893ef3d82f9a4ee
```

if I use the name of the branch:

```
 git checkout me/work
```

I get:

```
error: pathspec 'me/work' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

is it because I did a shallow clone? don't make much sense to me. The commit is on the remote, at the very least the branch/commit with that name is on the remote.

Update:

So I added an `--all` to `git fetch --all` and then ran `git branch -vv --all` and I see:

```
* master                4761f83 [origin/master] timeline event update date should not be the review date.  Every time it is inserted or updated the update date should be the current utc date
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master 4761f83 timeline event update date should not be the review date.  Every time it is inserted or updated the update date should be the current utc date
```

so the branch is not in *that* list, if that helps someone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the docs for `--depth` says,

> Implies `--single-branch` unless `--no-single-branch` is given

so if you want

> to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches

give `--no-single-branch` on your clone, or for one-off correction do the fetch yourself,

```
git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

or to retroactively shut off the single-branch setup

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and then `git fetch`.

Answer (score 4):

[A shallow clone is also, **by default**, a *single-branch* clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt):

> **--depth <depth>**
>   Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits. Implies `--single-branch` unless ...

A *single-branch* clone is just what it says: a clone that copies only one branch from the upstream.  (The underlying mechanism is via the default `fetch` refspecs, so you can temporarily override this for one fetch by supplying refspecs.)

If you want a shallow clone to copy more than one branch, you must convert it to a non-single-branch clone, or start it out as a non-single-branch clone.  To start out as one, keep reading the rest of the quoted sentence.  To change an existing single-branch clone to a two, three, or all-branch clone, see [How do I "undo" a --single-branch clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17714159/1256452)

Comment: yeah that makes sense, my answer with FETCH_HEAD seems to work tho

Comment: Yes: you're overriding the default fetch refspec. The refspec you gave said to grab their `me/work`, remembering the commits temporarily via your `FETCH_HEAD` file, without creating any other name. The `git checkout -b` then creates a new local branch name using the data remembered (until the next `fetch` anyway) in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing a shallow clone you may want to specify a branch you are going to fetch:

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=me/work <repo> app
```

Comment: this is in a Dockerfile, the clone part is cached, I don't know what branch I want to checkout until later, which is pretty normal in general

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how shallow clone works. If you want to switch between branches - then you need to clone the whole tree.

Comment: yeah I think you're right, I added an answer that works (I think)

Answer (score 1):

I think this way works if you do a shallow clone

```
git fetch origin me/work
git checkout -b temp FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to fetch and create explicitly the remote tracking branch (instead of relying on `FETCH_HEAD`)

And use the [`git switch` guess mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess) to create the local branch.

```
git fetch me/work:me/work
git switch me/work
```