# How to have my local repo pull from master, not a deleted branch?

Tags: git

I have a local repo that was initially cloned from a branch (using `git clone --single-branch`). That branch was merged into master and then deleted.

When I tried to switch to master in my local repo using `git checkout master`, I got `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`  I had to do a `git checkout -b master` instead, and then `git status` said I am on branch master.

But when I do a `git pull`, it is still pointing to the deleted branch because it prints out `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/deleted-branch-name`.

How do I remove any remaining references to the deleted branch, so that `git pull` pulls from the master branch?

Comment: Did you make a *single-branch* clone (using `git clone --depth` or `git clone --single-branch`)?

Comment: Yes I made a single-branch clone.

Comment: That's the root of the problem, then. You'll need to either convert it back to a full clone (or replace it with a full clone) or change your single branch to be the branch `master`.

Comment: Thanks, I converted it to a full clone using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17714718/782011).

Answer (score 1):

When you clone a single branch, you only get that single branch, not `master`. When you then execute `git checkout -b master`, you are checking out to a branch you are creating on the fly. That is, you create a local branch called `master` and you checkout to that branch. Of course, that `master` branch is not related to your `remote master`. You could have used `git fetch origin` to get all the branches of the repo. Example:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b master # creates a new branch called master
git merge origin/master # merge the master branch from the repo into yours
```