# How to get whole git history afterwards "git clone --depth=1"?

Tags: git, git-commit

One of my git repo was huge, containing huge assets to previous commits.

Somehow I was able to clone repo(made runnable) using `git clone <repo> --depth=1`.

I want to get all the previous commits on same local repo.

Thank You.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`git pull --unshallow` should do it.

*From ([git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))*

> `--unshallow`
>
> If the source repository is complete, convert a shallow repository to a >complete one, removing all the limitations imposed by shallow repositories.
>
> If the source repository is shallow, fetch as much as possible so that the >current repository has the same history as the source repository.

`pull`'s `--depth`, `--deepen=` and `--shallow-since` may also be relevant.

*From ([git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))*

> `--depth=<depth>`
>
> Limit fetching to the specified number of commits from the tip of each remote branch history. If fetching to a shallow repository created by git clone with --depth= option (see git-clone[1]), deepen or shorten the history to the specified number of commits. Tags for the deepened commits are not fetched.
>
> `--deepen=<depth>`
>
> Similar to `--depth`, except it specifies the number of commits from the >current shallow boundary instead of from the tip of each remote branch history.
>
> `--shallow-since=<date>`
>
> Deepen or shorten the history of a shallow repository to include all reachable commits after `<date>`.

---

`git` guru @torek points out the following:

> Be aware that a clone made with --depth is also, by default, a single-branch clone. To make it a full clone you will need to undo this single branch effect.

How to do it is shown at [How do I "undo" a --single-branch clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714159/how-do-i-undo-a-single-branch-clone).

Comment: Be aware that a clone made with `--depth` is also, by default, a *single-branch* clone. To make it a full clone you will need to undo this single branch effect.