# Git blame delivers different results in Gitlab CI than on local machine

Tags: bash, git, gitlab

I've created a small shell script that uses the output of `git blame` to generate some reports. This works great on my local machine. But then I wanted to integrate the shell script in our gitlab ci/cd pipeline and for some reason when I run `git blame` on gitlab, all lines are attributed to me and the latest commit.

This is what I put in my pipeline file to debug this issue:

```
run-git-blame:
  stage: mystage
  image: alpine
  before_script:
    - apk add bash git gawk
    - git status
    - git log
  script:
    - git blame HEAD -- somefile.txt
```

When I run `git blame HEAD -- somefile.txt` locally I get:

```
4588eb70a0b (DXXXXXXX                     2019-05-07 15:35:22 +0200    1) abc=123
4588eb70a0b (DXXXXXXX                     2019-05-07 15:35:22 +0200    2) def=456
4588eb70a0b (DXXXXXXX                     2019-05-07 15:35:22 +0200    3) ghi=789
4588eb70a0b (DXXXXXXX                     2019-05-07 15:35:22 +0200    4) jkl=abc
4588eb70a0b (DXXXXXXX                     2019-05-07 15:35:22 +0200    5) mno=def
[...]
```

However the gitlab ci output looks like this:

```
^5e95b8e5 (Sebastian Gellweiler 2020-09-24 09:32:54 +0200    1) abc=123
^5e95b8e5 (Sebastian Gellweiler 2020-09-24 09:32:54 +0200    2) def=456
^5e95b8e5 (Sebastian Gellweiler 2020-09-24 09:32:54 +0200    3) ghi=789
^5e95b8e5 (Sebastian Gellweiler 2020-09-24 09:32:54 +0200    4) jkl=abc
^5e95b8e5 (Sebastian Gellweiler 2020-09-24 09:32:54 +0200    5) mno=def
[...]
```

Bu I have definitevly not touched the file being inspected.

The `git status` command outputs the following on the server:

```
HEAD detached at 5e95b8e5
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

And this looks fine, as 5e95b8e5 is the hash of the latest commit.

What also puzzles me is the output of `git log` on gitlab because it only shows one commit and no history:

```
commit 5e95b8e5efcfd155d4248f4849b848e9f1580a20
Author: Sebastian Gellweiler <sebastian.gellweiler@dm.de>
Date:   Thu Sep 24 09:32:54 2020 +0200

    ...
```

This is what the history on my local machine looks like:

```
commit 5e95b8e5efcfd155d4248f4849b848e9f1580a20 (HEAD -> feature/XXX)
Author: Sebastian Gellweiler <sebastian.gellweiler@example.org>
Date:   Thu Sep 24 09:32:54 2020 +0200

    ...

commit bc689804f87d906e1b2435249fc1aaaf32e49b20
Author: Sebastian Gellweiler <sebastian.gellweiler@dm.de>
Date:   Wed Sep 23 18:40:18 2020 +0200

    XXX

commit 9d6fa2336aee0938aef0bd78563b6f12dee5934f (master)
Merge: 90ef282515 3eabec88c2
Author: XXXX <XXX@example.org>
Date:   Thu Sep 17 08:31:20 2020 +0000

    XYZ
    
[...]
```

As you can see the top commit hash is the same on my local machine and on the remote.

I'm stuck here. Anybody has an explanation for this discrepancy?

Comment: 1) You're checked out to an old commit which cannot see 5e95b8e5. 2) local repo is out of sync with the remote. What happens if you `git fetch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have GitLab configured to make a *shallow clone* that has depth 1.  Since it has only one commit, every file in the repository is the way it is due to the (single, one) commit that is in the repository, so that's the hash ID it produces.

In particular, this notation:

```
^5e95b8e5
```

indicates that Git knows there is something before `5e95b8e5`, but not *what it is*, which in this case is the mark of a shallow repository.  (Technically it's a *boundary mark* and you'd see it on some other commit if you had used a range expression, such as `abc1def..HEAD`.  You can use the `-b` option, or some configuration items, to alter how these are shown.)

Comment: Thanks! After running git pull --unshallow origin "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" it works. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58704543/1245992.

Comment: I generally recommend avoiding `git pull` in scripts (because it obeys user configurations, among other things). Not sure how GitLab configs work but if there's a yaml file with settings, see if there's a way to fetch without `--depth` (or with a suitable number, although there's rarely a single suitable number) in the first place, rather than trying to fix it afterwards.

Comment: I tried turning off shallowing for this single job, but that didn't worked and I can't turn it off for the hole pipeline because that is just not performent enough. So I guess a git fetch will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Git commits only connect to their parents, Git can only go through history backwards. If you have a commit checked out that's older than 5e95b8e5 you will not see it in `git blame` nor `git log`.

Alternatively, your local repo is out of datee and you need to `git pull`.

Comment: The repo is in sync. Also 5e95b8e5 doesn't touch the file in question.