# Master branch not able to pull from remote using Git

Tags: git

I'm trying to rebase my feature branch to the master branch. But, when I try to pull or fetch using git, it's not even pulling the master branch from the remote to the local.

Here are the steps which I tried

```
$ git merge origin/master
merge: origin/master - not something we can merge

$ git merge master
merge: master - not something we can merge      

$ git branch -r
origin/feature

 git branch -a
 * feature
  remotes/origin/feature


$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin

$ git pull --all
Fetching origin
Already up to date.
```

I cloned in the following way

```
git clone https://github.optum.com/<Repo details> --branch feature --single-branch
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have a `master` branch. What is the output of `git branch` with no options, or `git branch -a`? Along similar lines: what is the output of `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`? How did you make the clone?

Comment: @torek, updated in the question. Please check

Comment: Clone without using `--single-branch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the fact you cloned with `--single-branch`, this changer the repos configuration to scope all commands to that specific branch for the remote. [You can undo the command or add another branch as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17714718/736079).

```
git remote set-branches --add origin [remote-branch]
git fetch origin [remote-branch]:[local-branch]
```

Answer (score 2):

From `git help clone` for the `--single-branch` option:

> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the --branch option or primary branch remote’s HEAD points at. Further fetches into the resulting repository will only the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning. If the at the remote did not point at any branch when --single-branch clone was made, no remote-tracking is created.

This would suggest your clone has only cloned the history of the **feature** branch, hence why your local repository has no idea that a **master** (or any other branches) exist on the remote.

As I was typing this, @jessehouwing [answered with instructions how to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58991038/9118298)