# Using GIT to get another branch when the clone was done with --depth 1

Tags: git, github

I've recently been introduced to --depth 1 for git clone.  Apparently this doesn't get all the history and is much faster.  I used:

git clone --depth 1 -b develop https://github.MyCompany.com/CoolProduct/CoolProduct.git

This allowed me to play, modify and branch off the develop branch.

However, now I want to look at another branch "BillsFeature"
I tried: git checkout BillsFeature and got
error: pathspec 'BillsFeature' did not match any file(s) known to git

This makes some sense to me.  Presumably because I used --depth 1, I didn't pull down the branch names. **How do I get another branch?**
I don't need the history with BillsFeature either.
I should say that I tried:
git fetch --depth 1 origin BillsFeature
and something seemed to happen. However, when I did git status I got:

On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: It's not immediately obvious that this is a duplicate, but in fact it is, because `--depth` implies `--single-branch` unless you also add `--no-single-branch`.

Comment: I don't see how it's a duplicate.  Given that I used --depth (same as --single-branch), how do I get other branches?

Comment: Also, it seems like the accepted answer is just getting the entire history and all branches?  Can I just get one branch at a time with no history?

Comment: Because `--depth 1` implies `--single-branch`, you got only one commit for one branch. Use the `--no-single-branch` option during cloning to get one commit for *each* branch (and hence the right number of remote-tracking names), or use the accepted answer to update your existing clone, then run `git fetch --depth 1` to update things so that you have 1 commit for each remote-tracking name.

Comment: (If you'd like, I'll re-open this for direct answers, rather than the sort of indirect realization that `--depth` implies `--single-branch` so therefore `--no-single-branch` is required to defeat it.)

Comment: You can always do `git fetch --unshallow`, please see the https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802238/2443502

Comment: @MarcinKłopotek: `--unshallow` still leaves one with a single-branch clone; the primary issue here is making it non-single-branch. (After that, the secondary issue is what depth the clone should have.)

Comment: Personally @torek, I'd prefer you put the part about "use the accepted answer" and "git fetch --depth 1" in an answer and let me accept it. I think it would be useful for folks.  If I were rewriting the question today, I'd write "I have a large GIT repository. I'd like to get our main branch called develop as quickly as possible, but I'd also like to be able to get other branches later. How do I do this?"  I don't see any questions/answers that directly answer this question.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, I've re-opened it and will put in an answer that mostly refers to the other answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem here is that `git clone`'s `--depth` option turns on `--single-branch` as well.  To defeat that at clone time, use `--no-single-branch`.  To defeat it afterwards, see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17714718/1256452) to [How do I "undo" a --single-branch clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17714159/1256452)

Note that after de-single-branch-ing the clone you have, you will have to run `git fetch --depth 1` again.  This will retrieve the rest of the branch names from the repository you cloned—all of them become remote-tracking names; see the details below—and allow you to run `git checkout` on each such name to create a local branch with the same name.  You can also use `git remote set-branches --add` to add individual names to an existing remote; again, you'll need another `git fetch --depth`.

## Optional Reading: Details, or, why the above works

A Git repository—technically, a *non-bare* repository—really consists of the following three parts:

- a pair of databases, as described below;
- an *index*, by which Git knows what files to commit, i.e., which files to *track*, although there is much more to the index than just a list of files; and
- a *working tree* or *work-tree* in which you are able to use and modify *your* files.  These files are literally yours, and are not actually in Git at all.  The files inside Git, in the main database, are all read-only and in a special compressed and de-duplicated form that only Git itself can use.

When you run `git clone`, you have your Git copy the main database—the one holding all the commits and files and such—more or less wholesale, but have it read the other database, parse through it and *understand* it and write, to your clone, a *different* database.

The `--depth` flag affects the main database, so that you don't copy it wholesale.  The `--single-branch` flag—which, as we noted, `--depth` turns on automatically—affects the secondary database.  Before we go on, let's give the two databases names, so that we don't keep referring to some awkward phrase like ["the party of the first part"](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Party+of+the+First+Part):

- The thing I've been calling the "main database" is Git's *object store*.  This is a simple [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) in which the keys are hash IDs, and the values are Git's commits and other internal objects.<sup>1</sup>  Usually this is the largest part of a Git repository.<sup>2</sup>
- The second database is also a simple key-value store, with the keys being names—branch and tag names included, but also almost all of Git's other names<sup>3</sup>—and the values being hash IDs.  Each name stores just *one* hash ID, as that's all that is required.

So, to recap, `git clone` will—without `--single-branch` and `--depth` flags anyway—call up some *other* Git and have it list out all of its branch and tag and other names.  It will then use these names to find *all* the commits and other Git objects in the original repository, and have the other Git send over all of those objects.  The result is a full copy of the object database.<sup>4</sup>  You now have *all* of the commits from the other Git repository.

At the same time, though, your own Git takes all of their *names* and picks-and-chooses which *names* to take, and what to do with them.  In general, your Git takes all of their *branch* names—whose full spellings are things like `refs/heads/master`, `refs/heads/topic`, and so on—and *renames* them to become your own *remote-tracking* names instead: `refs/remotes/origin/master`, `refs/remotes/origin/topic`, and so on.  Your Git then creates its own independent name-to-hash-ID database, with *no* branch names in it.<sup>5</sup>

The end result is that immediately after this step of `git clone`, you have *all the commits* and *none of the branches!*  This situation is quickly rectified by the last step of `git clone`, though.  Provided you didn't say `--no-checkout`, the last step of `git clone` is to run `git checkout`, and this step actually *creates* one branch.  The branch name your Git creates is the one you supplied with the `-b` option.  If you did not supply a `-b` option, your Git asks the other Git which branch *it* recommends, and if all else fails, your Git assumes your own default initial branch name.<sup>6</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Each commit object refers to a (single) *tree* object, which holds the snapshot for that commit, and has metadata.  Each tree object holds an array of partial file names—name components, that will be strung together as needed—and another hash ID.  That hash ID identifies either another tree, or a *blob* object that stores some file's content.  Git builds up the files' full names by reading all the sub-trees as needed, and stores the full file names in its index, and then extracts the files using the names and blob hash IDs as seen in the index.  This isn't a complete description, but is why Git can't store empty directories: there's no way to put one into Git's index.

The object database can also contain *annotated tag objects*, each of which holds a hash ID, usually that of a commit.  These are how Git provides its annotated tags.

<sup>2</sup>There are exceptions: old repositories that for some reason keep accumulating new names, e.g., new branch and tag names, but hardly ever get any new commits.  But in general the object database is where most of the space is used, and most of the time for an initial clone.

<sup>3</sup>The other names include things like notes, in-progress bisection, names needed during some interactive rebases, and so on.  Basically any name that will store a single hash ID goes into this database.  Names that don't do that, such as the names of *remotes* like `origin`, don't go in here.  Those generally go in the `config` file in the `.git` directory.

This database is currently implemented rather poorly.  Sometimes the names are stored *as* directory-and-file-names *in the file system*, which means that on case-insensitive file systems such as the default ones on Windows and macOS systems, branch names become case-insensitive.  Sometimes the names are stored in a plain-text file named `packed-refs`, which makes them all case-sensitive as Git always intended.  A few special names, such as `HEAD`, never go into the packed-refs file at all and are instead always stored as individual files within the `.git` directory.  There is work going on right now to provide a proper database, to solve a bunch of issues here.

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the result can and usually will omit any objects that cannot be found *by* using the names.  We'll ignore this fine distinction here, though.

<sup>5</sup>Your Git will normally omit all of their non-branch non-tag names too.  How it handles their tag names is complicated, but in a normal (not single-branch, not depth-limited) clone you normally wind up copying all their tag names.

<sup>6</sup>This used to be just hard-coded as `master`, but it is now becoming configurable.

---

#### How `--single-branch` affects this

With the `--single-branch` option, your Git *doesn't* use all of their names.  Instead, your Git uses only the one branch name from your `-b` option, with the same default: if you don't supply `-b`, your Git asks their Git what they recommend, or falls back on yet another default.  Your Git then transforms that one branch name into one remote-tracking name.  It makes sure to ask their Git *only* for commits that are on that branch, in that other Git repository.

The end result is that you get *one* remote-tracking name, and some subset of all of their commits.  The final `git checkout` step then creates one local branch name: the *same* name your Git used when selecting the subset of commits to obtain.

#### How `--depth` affects this

Aside from automatically turning on `--single-branch`—but note that you can turn this *off* with `--no-single-branch`—what `--depth` does is to create a *shallow* clone.  To understand shallow clones completely, we have to get into graph theory.  (We won't go very far with this here, though.)

In Git, each branch name identifies *exactly one commit*.  But a branch in Git—if we ignore the question of [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) (we shouldn't ignore it, but we will here)—usually has a bunch of commits.  How does this work?

The answer is that each *commit* in Git contains the hash ID of some *earlier* commit.  In the usual simple case, we end up with a long string of commits, each of which points *backwards* to one earlier commit.  The *last* commit in this chain is the *tip of the branch*, or *tip commit*.

Let's draw a simple chain where we use one uppercase letter to stand in for the real hash ID of each commit.  Hash `H` will be the *last* one in the chain, and we'll say that this is branch `br1`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- br1
```

The *name* `br1` holds the *hash ID* of the last commit `H`.  That's how we can have Git fish it out of the object database (which, remember, is a simple key-value store: the hash ID is the key).  But inside the body of commit `H`, Git has stored the hash ID of *earlier* commit `G`.  So from `H` we can get `G`'s ID, and have Git look up commit `G` in the key-value store.  Meanwhile commit `G` has `F`'s ID, so we can walk backwards from `G` to `F`.

This is how Git works: *backwards*.  A name, like a branch or tag or remote-tracking name, stores *one* hash ID.  That's the commit we want, and then, if we want *all* the commits, Git walks backwards from that commit to the previous commit, and then keeps walking.  The *name* lets us get started; the commits themselves provide the rest of the path.

The path we traverse, and all the commits we collect as we walk this path, are the *reachable* commits on that branch.<sup>7</sup>  When two branches diverge, they have some sequence that's common to both:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- shared
            \
             K--L   <-- br2
```

Here, commits up through `H` are on *all three* branches, and the last two commits on each of the `br*` branches are unique to their branch.

This *reachability* idea is at the heart of Git.  It's also how `--depth` works.  If we say `--depth 1`, we are telling our Git: *When you obtain commits from the other Git, only go one step.*  If we use `--depth 1` here, we get:

```
             i--J   <-- br1

        g--H   <-- shared

             j--L   <-- br2
```

If we use `--depth 2`, we tell our Git: *When you obtain commits from the other Git, go two steps.*  This time we get:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
     f--G--H   <-- shared
            \
             K--L   <-- br2
```

Note that if `br2` had more commits unique to it, we wouldn't have the connection from `br2` back to `shared`.

The lowercase commit letters here denote the fact that Git knows there's a parent, but that these parents are marked as "missing on purpose".  More precisely, the hash IDs of the *shallow graft* commits are saved in a file called `shallow` in the `.git` directory.  Git knows not to try to load up these commits from the object repository, and that it's not a bug that they're missing.  Normally, that would be a bug.

Since they're missing-on-purpose, `git log` can't and won't show these commits, and it will be as if the shallow-grafted commits have no parents at all.  That's misleading in a way, but also what you should expect.  In most cases, it's harmless enough.

---

<sup>7</sup>This assumes the name we used was a branch name.  If we used a tag name, these are the commits reachable from the tag; if we used a remote-tracking name, these are the commits reachable from the remote-tracking name.  Since all names use the same system, each name provides some way to reach some set of commits.

---

#### It's the `git fetch` operation that gets commits

When we use `git clone`, we're really running the equivalent of a six-command sequence, five of which are Git commands:

1. `mkdir`, to create a new empty directory / folder;
2. `git init`, to create a new empty repository in the directory made in step 1;
3. `git remote add`, to add the name `origin`, or some other name of our choice, and a URL and a `fetch` configuration–that's the one we change to defeat the single-branch-ness;
4. `git config`, if needed, to add configuration options specified at the `git clone` command;
5. `git fetch`, to obtain commits and make remote-tracking names for the branch or branches chosen in step 3; and
6. `git checkout`, to create one local branch name and fill in Git's index and our working tree.

The `--depth` option is passed to the `git fetch` at step 5.  So if we have to adjust our `origin` remote configuration, to de-single-branch the clone because step 3 added the remote with one particular branch only (see [the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)), we have to run a new `git fetch`.  This new `git fetch` needs the same `--depth` option.

#### Conclusion

The `--depth` option to `git clone` turns on both `--single-branch`, which limits the set of names—and thus commits—obtained from the other Git repository, *and* passes the `--depth` to the fetch step, which limits the *depth* of commit-graph obtained from the other Git repository.  Using `--no-single-branch` at clone time inhibits the name-restricting while keeping the depth-restricting.  If you need to undo the name-restricting, or if you use `git remote` to update the set of restricted branch names, you must run `git fetch` again.  If you want that `git fetch` to have a depth restriction, you must pass `--depth` again.

Note that `git fetch` *does* respect *existing* shallow graft points, so in some cases, omitting the `--depth` is somewhat harmless.  For instance, if you have a single-branch clone of a repository that looks like this:

```
...--V--W--X   <-- main
            \
             Y--Z   <-- topic
```

and your single-branch clone is depth 1 on `main`, so that commit `W` is marked as a shallow graft point:

```
        w--X   <-- main
```

then adding `topic` without a `--depth` gets you:

```
        w--X   <-- main
            \
             Y--Z   <-- topic
```

That is, `main` didn't get any deeper this time.  But if the graph were:

```
...--V--W--X   <-- main
      \
       Y--Z   <-- topic
```

and you added `topic` and fetched without a new `--depth`, you would get:

```
...--V  w--X   <-- main
      \
       Y--Z   <-- topic
```

in your clone, which means you'd have to get commit `V` and everything earlier.  Note that commit `W` remains marked-and-missing: since it's missing, *your* Git can't see that `w` would connect back to `V` and your own Git will show you this as:

```
           X   <-- main

..--V--Y--Z   <-- topic
```

—which isn't *wrong*, technically, it's just misleading.

Comment: Thank you torek, both for the answer and the background information.  I suspect this will be useful to many people in the future. Git is widely used and the question of " I want to "get up and running quickly, but then get other branches later" is a common one I believe.  Thanks!