# Gitlab - Git differences between branch in CI versus HEAD

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-diff

I'm trying to get a list of the files that are different between the branch in execution of the Gitlab CI pipeline, and the ones on remote origin (called main).

I understand that when the gitlab CI pipeline runs, it does a clone of the specific branch, and it looks like it strips away all of the remote origins and branches?

So I do a git fetch to retrieve the remote branches, which nets me main (origin/main)

But from there I've tried every combination of git diff, git diff-tree, git diff merge-base, and I'm just getting nowhere, and fried.

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you mean by "a list of the files that are different between the branch in execution of the Gitlab CI pipeline, and the ones on remote origin (called main)" ?

Comment: Your CI system is probably set up to make a single-branch, shallow clone. This means you simply don't have the other commits. Using `git fetch` you can paper over the problem but you should also consider changing your CI system to use a full clone. There are tradeoffs however you do this.

Comment: @torek, that's actually what I did, git fetch to resolve the shallow clone. Gitlab CI apparently when it creates the pipeline doesn't do a full clone that I've found.  So, I added git fetch at the top of my pipeline statements.

Comment: @LeGEC, Basically my end goal is to get a list of files that have been changed in this branch, as compared to the main branch that's in production.

Comment: You can undo a shallow-and-single-branch clone but it takes more than just one `git fetch`: see [How do I “undo” a --single-branch clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17714159/1256452). That's why I suggest finding a way to make the CI system do a full clone in the first place: that might be simpler.

Comment: Good to know. According to the docs:

> To disable shallow clone and make GitLab CI/CD fetch all branches and tags each time, keep the value empty or set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the precise meaning of your definition, but I think you are looking either for :

```
git diff --name-only origin/main HEAD
```

or for :

```
git diff --name-only origin/main...HEAD # 3 dots
```

and perhaps for `--name-status` instead of `--name-only`

Comment: Generally speaking, "difference between" is definitely your first option. The second one is something else, something like "the difference between HEAD and the revision from which it was branched off of in the "origin/head" branch.  Maybe in this case they produce the same results, but using the first one is semantically more correct even so.

Comment: I'll give this one a shot, it's hard to remember the specifics of what I've tried. Because I might be able to do a git fetch to resolve the shallow clone, and do the git diff that way, since the local branch thinks it's the head?

Comment: Okay, so follow-up on this for anyone searching. @LeGEC is correct. The piece that was missing was the comment about removing the shallow clones. Once I did that, and used the second line, I got _exactly_ what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you do that (`git diff --name-only aTag...HEAD`) with a tag instead of a branch, note that "[`git diff --merge-base X other args...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/09dcbb486d964b59222136dd1668023098658eda/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> insisted that `X` must be a commit and errored out when given an annotated tag that peels to a commit, but we only need it to be a committish.
This has been corrected with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023).

See [commit 4adceb5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4adceb5a299164aad1ef9794cdcbdb232ab10299) (01 Oct 2023) by [Alyssa Ross (`alyssais`)](https://github.com/alyssais).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 09dcbb4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09dcbb486d964b59222136dd1668023098658eda), 13 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4adceb5a299164aad1ef9794cdcbdb232ab10299): fix `--merge-base` with annotated tags
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alyssa Ross</sup>

> Checking early for `OBJ_COMMIT` excludes other objects that can be resolved to commits, like annotated tags.
> If we remove it, annotated tags will be resolved and handled just fine by `lookup_commit_reference()`, and if we are given something that can't be resolved to a commit, we'll still get a useful error message, e.g.:
>
> ```
> error: object 21ab162211ac3ef13c37603ca88b27e9c7e0d40b is a tree, not a commit 
> fatal: no merge base found
> ```