# Fetch remote branch and create a fresh branch

Tags: git

This seems like a duplicate question but all the answers I was able to find don't do what I need:

- I cloned a single branch down (`dev`) using `--single-branch`.
- Now I need to fetch the repo's `main` branch down with the clean `main` from `remote` and track the `main` branch from there.

Update with background:

- I join a 5 year old repo with over 50+ branches. The `main` is in production and the others were branched out at some point in the past. Some were merged, some have been being merged to `main`, and some are just collecting dust.
- The branch I'm working on shares some files with the `main` one but it's been modified several times and about 25 commits ahead of the `main` one with multiple files and subfolders that (I assume) should not be merged with `main`.
- When I cloned the repo down, obviously I don't want to clone the whole 50+ branches that I'm not going to work on so I decided to clone only the branch that I need.
- Now, I need to check with the `main` branch to make sure my code isn't going to conflict with it so I need a "clean" `main` from remote/GibHub that people've pushed code to.
- I'd like to keep my code in my branch, clone just the `main` branch from GitHub with its code, and keep them separate.

I've tried:

- `git fetch <remote> <branch>:<local-branch>` and it does the job but it carries the files of my local `dev` to the new `main` local branch and I don't want to do that because there are many changes currently in `dev` that I don't want to merge. I just want a clean `main` from `remote`.
- `git switch`, `git checkout`, etc. as the answers I could find suggest but none of them works as expected.

Comment: "Carries the files of my local `dev` to the new `main`". It sounds like you just have files in your working directory that are untracked by `main`. They are not part of your `main` branch. `git status` should confirm that they are untracked.

Comment: If this is the case, you could move this files to some other directory, and they will be recreated when you do `git switch dev` again.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I understand they're not tracked by main but also I don't want to see/have them in the local `main` because I'm going to make changes to the `main` before pushing it up. Is there away to remove them from my working directory?

Comment: Yes, just move them to another directory with `mv` or (if you are sure that checking out `dev` will restore them) just delete them with `rm`.

Comment: I could do that but there're many files in different subfolders. It's possible but I'd like to avoid that. Is there another way?

Comment: You can use `git clean` to remove untracked files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know what `main` looks like. Since you have a `--single-branch` clone consisting of just `dev`, you need to add `main` to the branches you want to fetch:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin main
get fetch
```

Now the remote-tracking branch `origin/main` *is* the current state of `main`. If your desire is to compare it with `dev`, you can just use

```
git diff dev origin/main
```

However, if you want to see `main` as actual files and directories, you would need to create a local version of `origin/main`, which you would probably call `main`:

```
git branch --track main origin/main
```

Okay, so now local `main` exists. But you still can't see the actual files and directories on your computer, directly, because you did not *switch* to (or *checkout*) the local `main`. The normal way to do that would be:

```
git switch main
```

If you do that, Git will balk and refuse to proceed if you have any outstanding uncommitted edits in the tracked files of `dev`. Assuming there are none, Git will *change* your working tree (the files and directories you can see): it will *remove* the tracked files of `dev`, and it will *replace* them with the files of `main`. That's usually okay, but if you have *untracked* files in the working tree, and `main` doesn't have a version of those files, they will remain in place during the switch, and you would not be seeing in the working tree a correct representation of what `origin/main` looks like now.

It appears from your question that you don't like that.

So what can you do? Well, one possibility would be to *stash* your untracked files before doing the switch. But there's another possibility: you could use the `git worktree` command to check out `main` into a *different* working tree folder. That way, you can manually inspect *your* working tree, with `dev` checked out and all your untracked / edited files still in place, and the *other* working tree, with `main` checked out, at the same time in two different directories.

Comment: Thank you, @matt! This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Git is not about *files*.  Git is about *commits*.

The `--single-branch` option limits the set of *remote-tracking names* that your Git stores.  This may, or may not, reduce the *number of commits* obtained.  It has nothing to do with the number of branch names you can create and use locally (which makes it kind of the wrong name, but I have no suggestions for a better name: `--single-remote-tracking-name` might be *slightly* better, but is annoyingly verbose).

> Now I need to fetch the repo's `main` branch down with the clean `main` from `remote` and track the `main` branch from there.

I cannot make heads or tails of the phrase *with the clean `main` from `remote`*, but I can once again point out that Git is all about *commits*.  Every commit is fully, totally, completely read-only.  If some remote Git repository has commit `a123456`, and you have commit `a123456`, you and they have the *same commit*.  The contents of commit `a123456` in your Git repository exactly matches the content of commit `a123456` from that other Git repository, by definition.  The commit's hash ID *is* the commit, and you either have that commit, or you don't have that commit.  That's all there is to it: there's nothing "clean" or "dirty" about it.

If you insist on using `--single-branch` when running `git clone`, you can repair the single-branch-ness after the fact: see [How do I "undo" a --single-branch clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17714159/1256452)  If you like, you can use `git remote set-branches --add` to *add* one or more names to the set of remote-tracking names; see the same question, referring specifically to [Arno Fiva's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60846265/1256452).

Remember, Git is about *commits*.  If you have the commit, you have the commit.  If not, `git fetch` will get the commit, provided that the *other* Git has it and you're using a full, non-shallow clone.  If you're using single-branch and/or shallow clones, you may need to widen the number of remote-tracking names you use and/or deepen your clone until you get the commit.

To get the *files* **out** of the commit, you need a separate step, such as using `git checkout`, `git worktree add`, `git archive`, or similar.  Which of these to use (if any) depends on what you're really trying to do, and as I noted earlier, I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @Viet: looks like matt supplied the answer you wanted, which is similar to the one I linked above from Arno Fiva. I'll note that the carrying costs for a full clone (including the gathering-dust-branches) is *usually* quite small, but any one repository could be quirky: some branch in their Git repository might include a commit that holds 50 GB of DVD images, perhaps. :-) But usually `--single-branch` is not worth the price you pay in extra inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you @torek. I'll keep that in mind.