# Git weirdness - can't pull a branch

Tags: git

I know for a fact that a remote repo has a branch, let's call it `tricky-branch`. I can see it on gitlab. But I can't seem to find a way to pull it, or even see it, locally.

I've tried:

```
git fetch --all
git pull --all
git branch --all
```

```
$ git checkout origin/tricky-branch
error: pathspec 'origin/tricky-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I know I am pointing at the right repo and the connectivity is all right, because I can push to that repo. Just not pull.

Comment: Can you share the repository with us, or is it private? This would be much easier to solve as a concrete problem rather than an abstract problem.

Comment: Sorry, can't. Not my repo.

Comment: Some troubleshooting questions/ideas... Does the branch name have special characters in it? When you say `git branch --all` does not work, I assume you mean it's not displaying `origin/tricky-branch` in its output? If you go to GitLab and find the sha1 from the head of tricky-branch, then try `git show <that sha1>`, what do you get? Are you allowed to paste the actual name of the branch here, in case it might help?

Comment: Wow, `git clone` fixed it! So the problem was in the local repo. TBC...

Comment: Just curious, is RedHat officially involved in Gitlab? Good to see you here @joanis

Comment: I have nothing to do with RedHat or GitLab (except as a user), you probably have me confused with someone else with a similar name...

Comment: Yeah, that was meant for @larsks

Comment: Oh, OK, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: So, if a fresh clone fixed it, I have the feeling this was a glitch and there might not be much value in this question in the future. If you agree, I'd recommended deleting it.

Comment: Except if I saw the answer this morning, it would have saved me the day, along with two coworkers who tried to help. Besides, if RedHat is a GitLab contributor, as I suspect they are (Sr. Principal types aren't usually in the habit of cloning other people's repos for no reason), then maybe they'll submit a fix.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Red Hat is not involved in Gitlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I believe you had made a *single branch* clone.  Your new clone, where things worked, was an ordinary clone.  See [How do I "undo" a --single-branch clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17714159/1256452) (though these days `git remote set-branches origin "*"` is a "better" method for updating things, vs the accepted answer there).

(To find out, run:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

and see what gets printed.)

Meanwhile, let's address these as well:

> ```
> git fetch --all
> ```

This is sometimes useful.  It probably wasn't in your case.

> ```
> git pull --all
> ```

This is almost never useful.

> ```
> git branch --all
> ```

This is quite useful and showing the output *from* this would potentially have helped here.  The interesting question is, I think, "why is `--all` so inconsistent", or something along these lines.  The answer to that is basically that Git is a collection of ad-hoc tools: each one does its own thing, and some of them have useful `--all` options and some just don't.

What `--all` means to `git fetch` is *all remotes*.  In other words, if you have two or three remotes, such as `origin` + `upstream` + `fred`, a `git fetch --all` means that Git should run:

```
git fetch origin
git fetch upstream
git fetch fred
```

(in some order, or perhaps even in parallel).

If you have one remote named `origin`, `git fetch --all` means `git fetch origin`, which is what `git fetch origin` and `git fetch` also mean.  So `--all` does absolutely nothing!  **Most setups have only one remote.**  (I say this without doing any statistical analysis first, but I'm pretty confident. )  For setups with multiple remotes, `git remote update` is probably more appropriate here.

Meanwhile, `git pull` means—at one point, it meant this literally as `git pull` was just a small shell script—that you'd like Git to run `git fetch` for you, and then, if the `git fetch` succeeds, run a second Git command for you.  The `--all` option is passed to `git fetch`, where it usually has no effect for the reasons outlined above.

If it *does* have any effect at all, it has no effect on the *second command*, and the reason you're using `git pull` is to get Git to run the fetch *and the second command* and you probably care more about the results of the second command.  So even if `--all` actually did something, you *probably don't care*.  That's why it's almost never useful.  (If you see someone advising the use of `git pull --all`, you should probably suspect them of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and/or [xkcd #1597](https://xkcd.com/1597/).)

#### More about single-branch clones

It's worth exploring *what* a "single branch clone" really is, *why* you might sometimes want one, why you probably *don't* want one, and—perhaps most important—why you might have gotten one without intending to.  This gets into the mysteries of Git's *refspecs*, which are unfortunately somewhat complicated.

When we clone a repository in the ordinary way:

```
git clone [-b <branch>] <url>
```

we are telling our Git to:

1. make a new empty directory and run the remaining commands in that directory;
2. run `git init` to create a new, totally-empty repository;
3. run `git remote add origin url`;
4. run any additional `git config` or similar operations required;
5. **run `git fetch origin`**; and
6. run a final `git switch` or `git checkout` to *create* the branch we gave as our `-b` parameter, or the default branch if we didn't give `-b`.

Note step 5 in particular.  This is what copies *all the commits*—technically, all *reachable* commits—from the repository at the given URL.  It does not copy *any* branches though.  Instead, it reads out their branch names and changes those names into *remote-tracking names* in our new clone.  If they had branches `main` and `feature/one` and `feature/two`, we end up with remote-tracking names `origin/main`, `origin/feature/one`, and `origin/feature/two`.

A subsequent `git fetch origin` reaches back to the same URL and gets, from the Git that responds there, any *new* commits they have, that we lack, that we need in order to update our remote-tracking names.  You can *limit* this fetch:

```
git fetch origin feature/two
```

tells *your* Git that, despite them maybe having new commits on their `main` for instance, you're not interested in those new-to-you commits *unless* those commits are *also* on their `feature/two`.  You'd like to get all the new-to-you `feature/two` commits (using *their* `feature/two`, that is), and then when this is all done, update your own `origin/feature/two`.

The underlying mechanism that Git uses to do all this is the *refspec*, and there are some special cases here, because early versions of Git got this wrong.  In Git 1.8.2, Git was changed to make this better.  It's still downright weird, but it's better.

A *refspec* is a way of writing *two* names that will show up in *two different Git repositories* and relating them, or two *patterns for names* that will do the same thing.  The complete form of a refspec is:

- an optional leading plus sign `+`;
- a left-side name or pattern;
- a separating colon `:` character; and
- a right-side name or pattern.

Both `git fetch` and `git push` use refspecs, because both `git fetch` and `git push` *connect two repositories*.  The two repositories each have *their own branch names* (and other kinds of names) and, for `git fetch` in particular, we don't want *their* branch names to overwrite *our* **branch** names.  We want their *branch* names to become our *remote-tracking names*.

There are a lot of finicky details with refspecs, including the fact that (for historical reasons including that Git 1.8.2 change) fetch and push treat them differently when you leave out the colon.  But for the *default* operation, where you just run:

```
git fetch origin
```

for instance, Git has a *default fetch refspec*.  The default *value* for the `origin` refspec is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and now that we know that the format is `+` (optional) <name> `:` <name> it's suddenly obvious that the `refs/heads/*` on the left means *their branches* and the `refs/remotes/origin/*` on the right means *our remote-tracking names*.

This is *how and why* their `main` becomes our `origin/main`!

So, when you run `git clone <url>`, the new repository you get has `origin` as its one and only remote—this is why I'm so confident that most setups have one remote, because most people make a clone and then work with it and don't run `git remote add` on that to add a second remote—*and* its `remote.origin.fetch` is set to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

But if you use `--single-branch` during cloning, step 4 kicks in.  Here it is again:

4. run any additional `git config` or similar operations required;

What happens here is that we get:

```
git remote set-branch origin <branch>
```

or equivalently:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/<branch>:refs/remotes/origin/<branch>
```

This changes the *default fetch refspec*, so that `git fetch origin` or `git fetch` only fetches the commits *reachable from one branch name in their repository*, and only creates or updates the one remote-tracking name.

#### A two-branch clone

If we make a one-branch clone and then run:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin branch2
```

we'll find that `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` now contains:

```
+refs/heads/branch:refs/remotes/origin/branch
+refs/heads/branch2:refs/remotes/origin/branch2
```

This makes use of what Git calls a *multi-valued* configuration variable.  This fetch setting tells `git fetch` that by default, fetching from `origin` should check both `branch` and `branch2` for new-to-us commits, bring those over, and update *both* remote-tracking names.

Using `git remote set-branches` *without* `--add` tells `git remote` to erase the old settings and install new ones.

#### A shallow clone is a single-branch clone

Besides single-branch (or two or three-branch) clones, Git offers the `--depth` option during cloning, and during `git fetch` as well.  This makes an extra-limited clone in which Git deliberately *doesn't* get *all* the commits initially.  Instead, Git fills in the branch graph to the specified depth, from each branch tip commit selected.

In some very large repositories, using `--depth 1` speeds up cloning enormously.  Most CI systems take advantage of this to make shallow clones for speed reasons, for instance.  (Note that, due to a certain degree of silliness in the protocols, `--depth 2` is much better if you intend to `git push` from this shallow clone.  Also, not all implementations of Git protocols offer the ability to push from a shallow clone: e.g., GitHub Desktop apparently never intend to bother implementing it.)

But for no particularly good reason, using `--depth` with `git clone` turns on `--single-branch` *automatically*.  You can use `--no-single-branch` to turn it back off.  (Why they didn't just make you write `--depth 1 --single-branch` in the first place remains a mystery to me.)

The fact that shallow clones *are* single-branch clones, by default, has bitten many a casual Git user.  It's easy to turn a shallow clone into a full clone using `git fetch --unshallow`, but if you're not aware that your shallow clone is also a single-branch clone, you don't realize that you must *also* run `git remote set-branches origin "*"` first.  (Note the quotes around the asterisk: they are not *always* required, but are a good idea in general.)

Comment: Thank you! This answer is so good I had to give bounty.