# Clone specific branch from git

Tags: git, clone, bitbucket, pull

I have a repo in `bitbucket`, and i am using `git`.

So my branches are

```
master
develop_one
develop_two
```

When i use `git clone git@bitbucket.org:project/project.git`, i am getting only the master branch code, but i need to clone/pull only `develop_one` branch, so how to clone/pull only `develop_one` branch code ?

**Note:** The other branches(develop_one, develop_two) are not merged in to master, and dont want to merge until the functionality has been completed actually, so want to get/clone/pull only a specific branch code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone only one branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811434/clone-only-one-branch)

Comment: To clarify - do you want to clone or just pull from a single branch? Two different questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone a single branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try:

`git clone git@bitbucket.org:project/project.git -b develop_one --single-branch`

For already cloned repos use:

```
git fetch
git checkout develop_one
# Or more specific:
git checkout --track -b develop_one
```

This will track the develop_one branch from the remote.

Comment: I get `error: unknown option single-branch` when I do the the command you mention. What version of git are you running?

Comment: `git --version` returns `git version 1.8.4.2` (just one patch release behind I see)

Comment: Oh Ok. `--single-branch` came in [`1.7.10`](https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt) and I am on `1.7.9.5`. What an edge case :)

Answer (score 11):

Also, to add to @tomrbrujin 's answer, you can specify the name of the local destination directory in the **clone** command like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/example/example1.git -b branch_name --single-branch local_name
```

The final arg passed, **local_name** would create and name the local copy of the cloned remote directory "local_name."

Otherwise, the local directory name will only reflect the repo name, which here would be: **example**