# How to connect to my GitHub repositories from Terminal on mac?

Tags: git, github, ssh, terminal

how to connect to my Github account using Terminal?

To login to my server i use:

`ssh -l [login] [host]`

for example: `ssh -l kunass2 blue-world.pl`.

But now in one of my repositories on Github i would like to merge a few commits into one using rebase/squash. But i can do that only by terminal (i cannot do this directly on the web). 
The first thing is: **how to connect with my repository on Github?** and change it from terminal.

Important thing is: this is my forked repository. To be precised: **cdnjs**.

Comment: You want `git clone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

github have no [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) support. Instead, you have to install [git](/questions/tagged/git) and use it in a terminal by example :

```
cd /path/where/you/want/your/clone
git clone git://user@host/path/to/git/repo.git
```

you can find the clone url in the main page of your github project.

Comment: I do not want to clone this repository. Just to make some changes on it.

Comment: To have a copy of your project, you need to clone it :)

Comment: but i do not want to have a copy. On the forked project from other account i made some changes, and i committed them. There is 5 commits. Now, all I need is to merge this 5 commits into one. And then a pull request to this forked project.

Comment: `git rebase` your **own** copy and commit. Then, `git push` and do a **pull request**

Comment: and do i have to get a copy of this repo? it takes ~500MB, almost 100 000 files

Comment: He guy, we are now in 2015 now, is it such a very BIG DEAL ?

Comment: One of the fundamental elements of git is that every developer has a copy of the repository.  If you edit files directly on GitHub you are [actually] working on a repository that belongs to you (the fork).  On the other hand, you can clone ONLY the branch you are interested in working on; saving most of the download. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033863/pull-specific-branch-from-git for an example)