# A complete backup of a git branch

Tags: git

What is the best way to backup a complete branch from a local git repository on one PC with the purpose of adding it to a local git repository on another PC.

In the case where the remote git repository server is offline due to failures on their end.

Comment: Push it somewhere (github) and check out from there ...

Comment: Why not just clone it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you can make a local clone of your current repo, [including only your branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930421/6309):

```
git clone -b mybranch --single-branch /path/to/your/local/repo.git
```

Then you can [make a bundle of that repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309), in order to easily save it (a bundle is a Git repo, compressed into *one* file).

If you have the possibility to make a [bare empty repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309) somewhere accessible (even through a simple shared folder), you could simply push your branch to it.

Comment: OK, this is looking promising. I am in the process of cloning. Bundle sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: @Knossos if you don't have the possibility to make an empty bare repo in a location acting as backup, bundle is indeed the next best option.

Comment: I should probably have added to the question - I am accessing the other PC by remote desktop software. In order to make this back up. It is not in the same area as I am. So a single file to transmit over the internet seems ideal to me.

Comment: That did it. I could transfer the bundle, add it as a remote to my local repository and everything went like a knife through butter.

Answer (score 3):

as oneliner for per minute backup ... ( this will bloat your git branch -a )

```
 git branch $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)--$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M") && git branch -a | grep -i $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

which is actually a 2 liner:

```
git branch $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)--$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M");
git branch -a | grep -i $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```