# How to clone the entire Github repo, after cloning only one branch?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I had cloned only one branch of a repo using

> git clone -b mybranch --single-branch git://sub.domain.com/repo.git

as explained in [Clone only one branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811434/clone-only-one-branch)

Now I want to get the entire repo, including all the branches into that very location.

How do I do this?

Comment: So I'm assuming you want to mirror the entire repo? https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/#mirroring-a-repository (not posting as an answer yet because I want to be sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `--single-branch` option, you end up with a configuration for the named remote in `.git/config` that looks something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/project/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/some_branch:refs/remotes/origin/some_branch
```

You can edit the configuration to reset the `fetch` configuration to the default:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

And then:

```
git remote update
```

And now you have the entire repository.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, since it is a rather large repo

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to just delete your current folder in that location and do normal git clone without all the flags:

```
git clone git://sub.domain.com/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a normal `git clone`, or you could do a complete duplicate/mirror that is **exactly** like the repo you're cloning with

`git clone --bare https://github.com/project/example.git`

This makes an exact duplicate that copies all the same refs /notes/ but no remote tracking. If you want that as well, then you do:

`git clone --mirror https://github.com/project/example.git`

The main [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare) is that `--mirror` sets up remote tracking, and whatever changes the repo you're mirroring from will be reflected in that mirror copy, it will overwrite it's own refs if needed, this is great for making multiple exact copies of the repo.

[More info on duplicating/mirroring a repository here](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/#mirroring-a-repository) and well as [how to properly mirror a git repository](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/)