# Purpose of --single-branch in git clone?

Tags: git

If we use the `git clone --branch` command, we're only copying the specified branch. What is the additional `--single-branch` param used fo? The documentation isn't clear to me.

TIA

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930421/6898523

Comment: Note: this work with submodules too now (Git 2.26, Q1 2020). See the last section of [How do I clone a single branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309)

Answer (score 15):

`--branch foo` automatically checks out `foo` after the clone is done but the clone downloads all the branches/tags and their reachable data.

`--branch foo --single-branch` tells git-clone to download only the data reachable from `foo` and check out `foo`.

Answer (score 8):

> If we use the `git clone --branch` command, we're only copying the specified branch.

No, you're cloning the entire repository and checking out that branch.

Answer (score 6):

As [ElpieKay answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48868492/1256452), `git clone --branch name url` is (my paraphrase) very roughly equivalent to:

`(git clone url && cd clone-target-directory && git checkout name)`

—i.e., it does a full clone.  (The parentheses above are because your main command interpreter does not change directories, so to simulate this, we need to do the `cd` in a sub-shell.)

The `git clone` command itself is short-hand for a series of more-primitive Git operations.  All get done in a new directory,<sup>1</sup> which I'll show as step 1 here, but note that your command interpreter itself stays outside this new directory so you end up having to do your own separate `cd` into the new directory.  Some options are incompatible or set other options, e.g., using `--depth` sets `--single-branch` by default.<sup>2</sup>  These are built in to a single command, rather than actually having `git clone` invoke each separate Git command, but assuming the whole clone succeeds, the effect is the same as if you manually run each of these commands.<sup>3</sup>

1. `mkdir target && cd target`.  The target directory is the one you specify, or the one computed from the URL you give to `git clone`.  See footnote 1 again.
2. `git init`, to create the new, empty repository.

   If you use the `--bare` or `--mirror` flags, `git clone` will configure the repository as a bare clone or mirror clone here, as if by running `git init --bare` instead.
3. `git remote add origin url`, so that the name `origin` identifies the *`url`* argument you give to `git clone`.

   You can get `git clone` to do additional configuration here as well; see the `-c` / `--config` option.

   If you use the `-o` or `--origin` flag, you can change the *name* from `origin` to any other name you like.  The rest of this assumes that you did not.
4. If you use the `--single-branch` flag, `git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/branch:refs/remotes/origin/branch`.  This overrides the default that `git remote add` creates.  The default setting tells Git: *bring over every branch.*  This particular setting tells Git: *bring over only the one named branch.*  See footnote 2 here as well.

   In either case, after bringing over each branch tip commit (and all commits reachable from these tips), your Git *renames* the branches it got from the other Git, so that instead of actual branch names, these become remote-tracking names: `refs/remotes/origin/whatever`.

   If you use the `--mirror` option during `git clone`, Git will override all of these and set the fetch refspec to `+refs/*:refs/*`.  (It's not clear how `--mirror` should interact with `--single-branch`.)
5. `git fetch origin`: this step actually contacts the other Git—the one at *`url`*—and obtains from it the list of references (branch and tag names, and so forth) to get the list of tip commits to bring over.  The commits brought over depend on the `remote.origin.fetch` setting set up in step 4, if any, or the default set up in step 3.
6. Last, as long as this is not a bare clone (neither `--bare` nor `--mirror`), `git checkout branch`.  The argument to the `git checkout` step is chosen from the best match in this list:<sup>4</sup>

   - the argument you gave to `-b` / `--branch`
   - the branch name recommended by the other Git
   - `master`

   This `git checkout` command actually *creates* your local branch, using the same commit that the copied remote-tracking name identifies.  For instance, if you said to check out `-b xyz`, your `git fetch` will have brought over their `refs/heads/xyz` and renamed it to your `refs/remotes/origin/xyz`.  This `git checkout` then creates your own `refs/heads/xyz`, pointing to the same commit as your `refs/remotes/origin/xyz`, which of course points to the commit that *their* Git has (or had) as their `refs/heads/xyz`.

   (If you name a tag with your `-b` option, your Git creates *no* branches in your own repository.)

Hence, while both `-b` and `--single-branch` allow you to pick your own branch name, they have different effects *earlier* in the sequence of steps that `git clone` runs.

---

<sup>1</sup>The exception to this rule occurs when you run `git clone url directory` to tell `git clone` to put the clone into the given but *existing* directory, e.g., `.`.  For Git to allow this, the given directory must be empty.

<sup>2</sup>If you use `git clone --single-branch` (even if it's just implied), Git will clone the particular branch you specify with `-b` / `--branch`.  If you don't choose one with this option, Git will choose one for you, using the method shown in step 6.

<sup>3</sup>If the `git clone` operation *fails*, Git will clean up after itself, removing the entire new directory, or everything created in the empty directory.

<sup>4</sup>In order to choose the right branch, your Git has to ask the other Git what its `HEAD` is.  In Git versions before 1.8.5, there is no way to find out.  If either Git involved in the cloning process predates 1.8.5, your Git will have the other Git list all its branch names and their hash IDs, and then list the hash ID that goes with their `HEAD`, and *guess* which branch that might be.  If both Gits are at least 1.8.5, your Git will just get their Git to send you their recommended branch name—there's no need to guess when both Gits support the "read symbolic HEAD" capability.